# How to do 'lateral view explode()' in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do this :

```
# input:
        A   B
0  [1, 2]  10
1  [5, 6] -20
# output:
   A   B
0  1  10
1  2  10
2  5 -20
3  6 -20
```

Every column A's value is a list

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[1,2],[5,6]],'B':[10,-20]})
df = pd.DataFrame([[item]+list(df.loc[line,'B':]) for line in df.index for item in df.loc[line,'A']],
                  columns=df.columns)
```

The above code can work but it's very slow

is there any clever method?

Thank you

Comment: refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468402/how-to-explode-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-separate-rows

Comment: With recent pandas use `DataFrame.explode`

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[[1,2],[5,6]],'B':[10,-20]})
df.explode('A')

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Method 1 (OP)

```
pd.DataFrame([[item]+list(df.loc[line,'B':]) for line in df.index for item in df.loc[line,'A']],
             columns=df.columns)
```

#### Method 2 (pir)

```
df1 = df.A.apply(pd.Series).stack().rename('A')
df2 = df1.to_frame().reset_index(1, drop=True)
df2.join(df.B).reset_index(drop=True)
```

#### Method 3 (pir)

```
A = np.asarray(df.A.values.tolist())
B = np.stack([df.B for _ in xrange(A.shape[1])]).T
P = np.stack([A, B])
pd.Panel(P, items=['A', 'B']).to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Thanks @user113531 for the reference to Alexander's answer.  I had to modify it to work.

#### Method 4 (@Alexander) [LINKED ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468402/how-to-explode-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-separate-rows)

(Follow link and Up Vote if this was helpful)

```
rows = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for a in row.A:
        rows.append([a, row.B])

pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df.columns)
```

---

#### Timings

**Method 4** (Alexander's) is the best followed by **Method 3**

[image]