# Merge two data frames on multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames which look like this

**df1**

```
              name  ID      abb
     0         foo  251803  I
     1         bar  376811  R
     2         baz  174254  Q
     3      foofoo  337144  IRQ
     4      barbar  306521  IQ
```

**df2**

```
          abb    comment
     0      I       fine
     1      R     repeat
     2      Q      other
```

I am trying to use pandas `merge` to join the two data frames and simply assign the `comment` column in the second data frame to the first based on the `abb` column in the following way:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='abb')
```

resulting in:

```
              name  ID      abb  comment
     0         foo  251803  I       fine
     1         bar  376811  R     repeat
     2         baz  174254  Q      other
```

This works well for the unique one letter identifiers in `abb`. However, it obviously fails for more than one character.

I tried to use `list` on the `abb` column in first data frame but this results in a `KeyError`.

What I would like to do is the following.

1) Seperate the rows containing more than one character in this column into several rows

2) Merge the data frames

3) Optionally: Combine the rows again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
print (df1)
     name      ID  abb
0     foo  251803    I
1     bar  376811    R
2     baz  174254    Q
3  foofoo  337144  IRQ
4  barbar  306521   IQ

#each character to df, which is stacked to Series
s = df1.abb.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x)))
           .stack()
           .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
           .rename('abb')
print (s)
0    I
1    R
2    Q
3    I
3    R
3    Q
4    I
4    Q
Name: abb, dtype: object

df1 = df1.drop('abb', axis=1).join(s)
print (df1)
     name      ID abb
0     foo  251803   I
1     bar  376811   R
2     baz  174254   Q
3  foofoo  337144   I
3  foofoo  337144   R
3  foofoo  337144   Q
4  barbar  306521   I
4  barbar  306521   Q
```

Comment: the columns come as I have listed above. So I do not need to join them. However, I cannot use split on 'IRQ' to seperate the string into 'I', 'R' and 'Q' to use stack to obtain three columns.

Comment: Very insightful answer. Thank you very much. I had the list already figured but not using apply which is the hat trick here.

Answer (score 1):

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38432346/2336654) for various ways to explode on a column

```
rows = []
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    for a in row.abb:
        rows.append([row['ID'], a, row['name']])

df11 = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df1.columns)

df11.merge(df2)
```

[image]

Comment: looking at your original answer, this might be slightly faster than the above solution @piRSquared