# Pandas explode - cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a data frame `df`:

```
   C1      C2      C3      C4               C5
0  [A]     [1]     s1      [123]            t1  
1  [A]     [1]     s2      321              t2
2  [A,B]   [1,2]   s3      [777,111]        t3
3  [B]     [2]     s4      145              t4
4  [B]     [2]     s5      [990]            t5
5  [A,B,B] [1,2,2] s6      [124,125,765]    t6
6  [A,A]   [1,3]   s7      119              t7
```

I want to explode everything out, so I have been doing

`df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)`

However, this gives me `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. I have traced the culprit to the row 6 (last row) of `df`. I understood when I got this before when I had things in `C1` that were not the same length as what was in `C2`. But I don't understand what's wrong with exploding that last row.

If I do `pd.DataFrame([[['A','B'],[1,2],'s7',119,'t7']]).apply(pd.Series.explode()`, it works fine and as expected giving me the following:

```
   C1      C2      C3      C4         C5
0  A        1      s7      119        t7  
1  A        3      s7      119        t7
```

I can't figure out why that last row causes an error when it is part of the whole data frame. I have check the index and it is all unique.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to unnest (explode) multiple list columns in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846765/efficient-way-to-unnest-explode-multiple-list-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, but this is where is got `apply(pd.Series.explode)`. I don't know why it's not working on that last row.

Comment: @formicaman can you give the first dataframe in a way easier to duplicates? like with `df.head(7).to_dict()`?

Comment: Evidently every list must be the same length to use `.apply(pd.Series.explode)` -- more details here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59330040/13608599

Comment: Exact expected output?

Answer (score 6):

Cleanup as you go and it works.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1': [["A"], ["A"], ["A","B"], ["B"], ["B"], ["A","B","B"], ["A","A"]],
 'C2': [[1], [1], [1,2], [2], [2], [1,2,2], [1,3]],
 'C3': ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5', 's6', 's7'],
 'C4': [[123], 321, [777,111], 145, [990], [124,125,765], 119],
 'C5': ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 't6', 't7']})

df.explode("C1").reset_index().drop("index",1).explode("C2").reset_index()\
    .drop("index",1).explode("C4").reset_index().drop("index",1)
```

**output**

```
  C1 C2  C3   C4  C5
0  A  1  s1  123  t1
1  A  1  s2  321  t2
2  A  1  s3  777  t3
3  A  1  s3  111  t3
4  A  2  s3  777  t3
5  A  2  s3  111  t3
6  B  1  s3  777  t3
7  B  1  s3  111  t3
8  B  2  s3  777  t3
9  B  2  s3  111  t3
```

Comment: 2023: This now raises `TypeError: DataFrame.drop() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/q/76411055/12846804, one must specify that `.drop("index",1)` is actually `.drop("index",axis=1)`. Hence use `df.explode("C1").reset_index().drop("index", axis=1).explode("C2").reset_index().drop("index",axis=1).explode("C4").reset_index().drop("index",axis=1)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do

`df = df.apply(lambda x: x.explode(ignore_index=True), axis=0)`

Comment: Doesn't yield the expected output when I try it. Would you share your output? 11 rows, some `NaN`.