# ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis in explode

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-explode

I am trying to expand the dataframe from one row to multiple rows based on two columns.

Following is the snapshot of the actual data.

```
initial_row_index        Date        Product_ID               No_of_items
1                        2021-07-11  ['A13N', 'A4BE','5GH$']  [3,5,1]
2                        2021-07-12  ['A13N', 'X9HE','7H3T']  [7,2,4]
3                        2021-07-13  ['A4BE', 'X9HE']         [8,4]
```

I want the transferred output to be as follows

```
initial_row_index        Date        Product_ID       No_of_items
1                        2021-07-11  A13N             3
1                        2021-07-11  A4BE             5
1                        2021-07-11  5GH$             1
2                        2021-07-12  A13N             7
2                        2021-07-12  X9HE             2
2                        2021-07-12  7H3T             4
3                        2021-07-13  A4BE             8
3                        2021-07-13  X9HE             4
```

To get this result I tried the following

```
df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

*I have already verified that I don't have any duplicate index in the dataframe. The length of the lists in both the column for each row have same no of elements*. After looking into the error found few similar questions where the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63140339/18588590) suggested to explode the df column by column as follows.

```
df.explode("Product_ID").reset_index().drop("index",1).explode("No_of_items").reset_index().drop("index",1)
```

But the above solution is giving me 9 rows instead of 3 rows after exploding the 1st row.
How can I solve the value error or achieve the desired out put using any other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.explode(['Product_ID', 'No_of_items'])
>   initial_row_index   Date    Product_ID  No_of_items
0   1   2021-07-11  A13N    3
0   1   2021-07-11  A4BE    5
0   1   2021-07-11  5GH$    1
1   2   2021-07-12  A13N    7
1   2   2021-07-12  X9HE    2
1   2   2021-07-12  7H3T    4
2   3   2021-07-13  A4BE    8
2   3   2021-07-13  X9HE    4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame as df




df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2021-07-11', '2021-07-12', '2021-07-13'],
                   'Product_ID': [[
                       'A13N', 'A4BE', '5GH$'], ['A13N', 'X9HE', '7H3T'],
                       ['A4BE', 'X9HE']],
                   'No_of_items': [[3, 5, 1], [
                       7, 2, 4], [8, 4]]})

print(df.to_string())


"""
         Date          Product_ID No_of_items
0  2021-07-11  [A13N, A4BE, 5GH$]   [3, 5, 1]
1  2021-07-12  [A13N, X9HE, 7H3T]   [7, 2, 4]
2  2021-07-13        [A4BE, X9HE]      [8, 4]

"""

aa = df.set_index('Date').apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
print(aa.to_string())

"""
        Date Product_ID No_of_items
0  2021-07-11       A13N           3
1  2021-07-11       A4BE           5
2  2021-07-11       5GH$           1
3  2021-07-12       A13N           7
4  2021-07-12       X9HE           2
5  2021-07-12       7H3T           4
6  2021-07-13       A4BE           8
7  2021-07-13       X9HE           4
"""
```