# TypeError: DataFrame.drop() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a large file that I'm trying to reduce using dataframe.drop
Here's my code:

```
probe_df = pd.read_csv(csv_file,header = 9233, nrows = 4608)
# Get rid of stuff
c_to_drop = 'Unnamed: ' + str(count_tp+1)
probe_df = probe_df.set_index("Chamber ID").drop(c_to_drop,1)
```

When I ran this, I got this error message:

```
probe_df = probe_df.set_index("Chamber ID").drop(c_to_drop,1)
TypeError: DataFrame.drop() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I don't understand why I got the error and how to fix it. Please help!

I'm a newbie and I tried looking online for a solution but I'm still quite new and didn't see anything that matched my issue exactly.

Comment: assuming the `1` is intended to be axis, try doing `probe_df.set_index("Chamber ID").drop(c_to_drop,axis=1)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas-dataframe-drop), the source for drop would be

> `DataFrame.drop(labels=None, *, axis=0, index=None, columns=None, level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise')`

The `*` represents the end of allowed positional arguments. This indicates that the positional arguments would be `labels`, and for python's error message this would likely be from the `self` positional argument that is not directly shown as it is implicitly supplied.

Therefore, doing `probe_df = probe_df.set_index("Chamber ID").drop(c_to_drop,1)` would be feeding 2 positional arguments into a function which only takes 1 (not including `self`).

By changing it to `probe_df.set_index("Chamber ID").drop(c_to_drop, axis=1)`, we convert the `1` from a positional argument to a keyword argument as required by the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
x = np.array( data.drop([predict],axis= 1))
```

this worked for me