# Splitting a cell in pandas into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-cleaning

It was a bit tricky to explain the problem.
I want to split a cell containing multiple string values delimited by commas into different rows. The df below is a small example but the real dataset contains up to 15 columns and 15 rows and each cell has 5 to 6 non unique string values in it that I need to separate into different rows.

How can we split the **original df** to the **transformed df**?

**Original df**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Privileges":['Type1','Type2','Type3'],"Super_Admin":["A1,A2,A3,A4","A1,B1,B2,B3, A4","C1,B2,C2,C3"], "Admin":["A1,A2","A1,B1,B2","B2, C1,C2"])
```

| Index | Privileges | Super_Admin | Admin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Type1 | A1,A2,A3,A4 | A1,A2 |
| 1 | Type2 | A1,B1,B2,B3, A4 | A1,B1,B2 |
| 2 | Type3 | C1,B2,C2,C3 | B2, C1,C2 |

**Transformed df**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Privileges":['Type1','Type1','Type1','Type1','Type2','Type2','Type2','Type2','Type2','Type3','Type3','Type3','Type3'],"Super_Admin":["A1","A2","A3","A4","A1", "B1","B2","B3", "A4","C1","B2","C2","C3"], "Admin":["A1","A2",'', '',"A1","B1","B2",'', '', "B2", "C1","C2", '']})
```

| Index | Privileges | Super_Admin | Admin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Type1 | A1 | A1 |
| 1 | Type1 | A2 | A2 |
| 2 | Type1 | A3 | -- |
| 3 | Type1 | A4 | -- |
| 4 | Type2 | A1 | A1 |
| 5 | Type2 | B1 | B1 |
| 6 | Type2 | B2 | B2 |
| 7 | Type2 | B3 | -- |
| 8 | Type2 | A4 | -- |
| 9 | Type3 | C1 | B2 |
| 10 | Type3 | B2 | C1 |
| 11 | Type3 | C2 | C2 |
| 12 | Type3 | C3 | -- |

Comment: Thank You for sharing the dataframe code as well. Most people just share the picture or text dataframe. You have the full code. It helps us to quickly work on the solution.

Comment: Should Type 3 have Super_Admin and Admin match the values. For ex: it has C1 B2 and B2 C1. Should it be C1 C1 and B2 B2 instead?

Comment: See the post from a few years ago on [exploding multiple columns...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846765/efficient-way-to-unnest-explode-multiple-list-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 4):

Breakdown of the steps below:

[zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) all the columns

Use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to pair `None` with values that do not have a pair

Combine the two lists into one, with [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

Create dataframe and [forward fill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) on the `Privileges` column

```
In [541]: step1 = zip(df.Privileges, df.Super_Admin, df.Admin)

In [542]: step2 = (zip_longest([first], second,last) 
                   for first, second, last 
                   in step1)

In [543]: step3 = chain.from_iterable(step2)

In [546]: (pd.DataFrame(step3, columns = df.columns)
             .assign(Privileges = lambda df: df.Privileges.ffill())
           )
Out[546]: 
   Privileges Super_Admin Admin
0       Type1          A1    A1
1       Type1          A2    A2
2       Type1          A3  None
3       Type1          A4  None
4       Type2          A1    A1
5       Type2          B1    B1
6       Type2          B2    B2
7       Type2          B3  None
8       Type2          A4  None
9       Type3          C1    B2
10      Type3          B2    C1
11      Type3          C2    C2
12      Type3          C3  None
```

To get more speed, you can move the split step into native python territory. pandas string methods are wrappers around python's string functions, as such they are not as fast as python's string functions.

Comment: Too fast :) I just got started and you already have it. Mine would have been too complex. This looks neat. upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

This is on option.
First make `Super_Admin` and `Admin` to a list. This is useful to use `pd.explode()`.

```
df['Super_Admin'] = df['Super_Admin'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
df['Admin'] = df['Admin'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))
```

Then call `explode` on both columns and fill the missing values with an empty string.

```
a = df.explode('Super_Admin')
b = df.explode('Admin')
for i in range(3):
    short = b.loc[i,'Admin'].values
    long = a.loc[i,'Admin'].values
    a.loc[i,'Admin'] = np.concatenate((short, ['']*(len(long)-len(short))), axis=0)
```

The output looks like this:

```
>>> a
  Privileges Super_Admin Admin
0      Type1          A1    A1
0      Type1          A2    A2
0      Type1          A3      
0      Type1          A4      
1      Type2          A1    A1
1      Type2          B1    B1
1      Type2          B2    B2
1      Type2          B3      
1      Type2          A4      
2      Type3          C1    B2
2      Type3          B2    C1
2      Type3          C2    C2
2      Type3          C3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the job with a **single** although substantially chained instruction:

```
result = df.set_index('Privileges').apply(lambda col:
    col.str.split(', ?', expand=True).stack())\
    .droplevel(1).reset_index().fillna('')
```

Steps:

- `df.set_index('Privileges')` - Set *Privileges* as the index column.
- `apply(lambda col:` - Apply to each column:

  - `col.str.split(', ?', expand=True)` - Break this column into separate
    columns (a *DataFrame*, with column names as consecutive integers).
  - `stack()` - Convert the above *DataFrame* into a *Series* with column
    names as the second *MultiIndex* level.
- `droplevel(1)` - Drop the unncessary index level.
- `reset_index()` - Change *Privileges* (the index column) to a regular column.
- `fillna('')` - Change each *NaN* into an empty string.

The result is:

```
   Privileges Super_Admin Admin
0       Type1          A1    A1
1       Type1          A2    A2
2       Type1          A3      
3       Type1          A4      
4       Type2          A1    A1
5       Type2          B1    B1
6       Type2          B2    B2
7       Type2          B3      
8       Type2          A4      
9       Type3          C1    B2
10      Type3          B2    C1
11      Type3          C2    C2
12      Type3          C3
```