# Cartesian product of rows in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

The data I'm working with (https://mushroom.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/files/PrimaryData/primary_data_edited.csv) has lists in some entries and I'd like to expand these lists as a cartesian product of their elements. The image below is two columns in the dataframe's header.

[image: data sample]

The output I'd like is something like:

```
cap-diameter | cap-shape
10 | x
10 | f
20 | x
20 | f
5 | p
5 | x
10 | p
10 | x
...
```

So I don't want the cartesian product of all of the entries in each column, just that of the respective rows. I think pd.explode() might be a good place to start but I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficient way to unnest (explode) multiple list columns in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846765/efficient-way-to-unnest-explode-multiple-list-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explode each column consecutively

```
df = df.explode('cap-diameter')
df = df.explode('cap-shape')
```