# python pandas can't explode columns and getting this error columns must have matching element counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have datafremae like this

```
        product_title   variation type  product_price       attribute
    0   Chauvet DJ      [Black, White]  [899.99, 949.99]    ['<p>apple,banana<p>', '<p>yewllow,orange,blue</p>']
```

my expected dataframe will be look like this

```
product_title  variation type        product_price            attribute
Chauvet DJ     Black                  899.99               <p>apple,banana<p>
Chauvet DJ     White                  949.99               <p>yewllow,orange,blue</p>
```

I tried this code:

```
        data["variation type"] = data["variation type"].apply(str).str.strip('[]').apply(str).str.replace("'","").apply(str).str.split(',')
        data["product_price"] = data["product_price"].apply(str).str.strip('[]').apply(str).str.replace("'","").apply(str).str.split(',')
        data["attribute"] = data["attribute"].apply(str).str.strip('[]').apply(str).str.replace("'","").apply(str).str.split(r",(?=')",expand=True)
        data = data.explode(['variation type', 'product_price','attribute'])
```

getting this error:

`ValueError: columns must have matching element counts`

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you need to get the results you expect:

```
data = {
    'product_title' : ['Chauvet DJ '],
    'variation_type' : [['Black', 'White']],
    'product_price' : [[899.99, 949.99]],
    'attribute' : ['[<p>apple,banana<p>, <p>yewllow,orange,blue</p>]']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['attribute'] = df['attribute'].apply(lambda x : x.replace('[','')).apply(lambda x : x.replace(']','')).apply(lambda x : x.split(', ', 1))
df.set_index(['product_title']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
```

You can read more about that here:
[Efficient way to unnest (explode) multiple list columns in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846765/efficient-way-to-unnest-explode-multiple-list-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: ArchAngelPwn I tried your code in my actual datframe but not working

Comment: Are you sure that your 'lists' are actually list? Could they simply be strings pretending to be lists?

Comment: they are actual list except few columns

Comment: Ok this technique would require them to actually be lists (of equal size) to work. Would you be able to turn those that aren't into a list and try again? If not can you update your original post to have which columns are not lists and I'll work with it to help make them into one?

Comment: if you see my attribute column here you can see `['<p>apple,banana<p>', '<p>yewllow,orange,blue</p>']` I have two item in my list but the problem as I use split by comma so it's aslo counting the comma inside my inverted quote `'<p>yewllow,orange,blue</p>']` . We need to only count comma after the inverted quote.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect if the attribute column is a string of a list