# I have a non normalised.db file and I need to create a dataframe df_exams using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm

I have  a non normalised.db file and I need to create a dataframe df_exams from the column 'Exams' of the non-normalised db file. Now the column exams of the non-normalised db file looks like this:

The original non-normalised file has columns of Student ID and Exams like this:

| Student ID | Exams |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | exam7 (2017), exam9 (2018), exam3 (2018),... |
| 2 | exam2(2017), exam2(2017), exam8 (2018),... |
| 3 | exam7 (2017), exam9 (2018), exam3 (2018),... |

And I need it like

| Student ID | Exam | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | exam7 | 2017 |
| 1 | exam9 | 2018 |
| 1 | exam3 | 2018 |

and so on. I am fairly new to python and appreciate the help.

I had written this code:

```
df_exams[['Exams','Year']]= df_exams.Exams.str.extract('(.)\s\((.\d+)', expand=True)
```

This does not produce the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated your dataframe using

```
import pandas as pd

my_df = pd.DataFrame({'Student ID': [1, 2, 3], "Exams": ["exam7 (2017), exam9 (2018), exam3 (2018)"]*3})
```

then I split your `Exams` column

```
my_df["Exams"] =my_df["Exams"].str.split(",")
```

this puts list of exams in `Exams` column.

Then I explode the column to make multiple rows:

```
my_df = my_df.explode("Exams")
```

which gives:

```
   Student ID          Exams
0           1   exam7 (2017)
0           1   exam9 (2018)
0           1   exam3 (2018)
1           2   exam7 (2017)
1           2   exam9 (2018)
1           2   exam3 (2018)
2           3   exam7 (2017)
2           3   exam9 (2018)
2           3   exam3 (2018)
```

Now I extract the values required using regex:

```
my_df["Year"] = my_df["Exams"].str.extract(r"\((\d{4})\)")
my_df["Exam"] = my_df["Exams"].str.extract(r"(exam\d{1,2})")
```

Which gives me a dataframe like this:

```
   Student ID          Exams  Year   Exam
0           1   exam7 (2017)  2017  exam7
0           1   exam9 (2018)  2018  exam9
0           1   exam3 (2018)  2018  exam3
1           2   exam7 (2017)  2017  exam7
1           2   exam9 (2018)  2018  exam9
1           2   exam3 (2018)  2018  exam3
2           3   exam7 (2017)  2017  exam7
2           3   exam9 (2018)  2018  exam9
2           3   exam3 (2018)  2018  exam3
```

You can filter the columns you want like:

```
my_cols = my_df[["Stzudent ID", "Exam", "Year"]]
```

and your dataframe will look like what you have posted here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved me. I was stuck in this for three days almost.

Comment: Hi, I had one doubt more.. if I had an additional column named scores having data like 68,70,52 for each cell value in exams exam7 (2017), exam9 (2018), exam3 (2018), would it be possible to enlist the scores for each exam and year as done previously?

Comment: Hi Abhipriyo, you can indeed do it, instead of exploding only "exams" like I have done here, you can set index to your Student ID and explode other columns like here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45846765/efficient-way-to-unnest-explode-multiple-list-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe .

Answer (score 0):

With your data here:

```
import pandas as pd
test_data =[
    [1,"exam7 (2017), exam9 (2018), exam3 (2018)"],
    [2,"exam2(2017), exam2(2017), exam8 (2018)"],
    [3,"exam7 (2017), exam9 (2018), exam3 (2018)"]
]
df = pd.DataFrame(test_data,columns=["Student ID","Exams"])
```

You can do it like this:

```
result = df.Exams.str.extractall(
    r"([^,]*?)\s*\((\d+)\)"
).reset_index(
    level=["match"],drop=True
).reset_index().rename(
    columns={
        0:"Exam",
        1:"Year",
        "index":"Student ID"
    }
)
```

And the `result` is:

```
    Student ID  Exam    Year
0   0   exam7   2017
1   0   exam9   2018
2   0   exam3   2018
3   1   exam2   2017
4   1   exam2   2017
5   1   exam8   2018
6   2   exam7   2017
7   2   exam9   2018
8   2   exam3   2018
```

Comment: sorry, but this is not giving the desired output. It just returns the same thing

Comment: @AbhipriyoBanerjee I added my output in the answer. I don't know if you really tried my code. Your code didn't work as you want because you use `str.extract` instead of `str.extractall` and your regex is not very suitable for that. Take a try with my code.

Comment: Hi, I tried your entire code. But it didn't work for me. Might be I implemented it wrong somehow because I didn't get the same output as yours.