# Pandas multi-column explode not working on Microsoft Azure

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, azure

I am trying to run Python code in Microsoft Azure and I am having issues with getting the explode function from the Pandas library to not throw errors.

The code which I have created runs perfectly fine locally on Spyder (with Pandas version 1.4.4) but it does not work when I use Azure to run my code. I know that the error is not occurring because there are rows which have lists of different lengths, as the code does run as desired when I run the code locally on Python with the same data. This issue only exists when I run my code using Azure.

When I try to use the multi-column explode function (which is available for Pandas version 1.3.0 and later), I get the following error: `column must be a scalar`

If I instead use the pandas.apply function with a custom-defined lambda function to explode only my desired columns (based on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63476456/21520545)), while keeping the rest of the columns as is, I get the following error: `cannot import name 'AggFuncType' from 'pandas._typing'`

I have included this block of code `os.system("pip install pandas==1.4.4")` in the code block which I made on Microsoft Azure, so I am not sure if my code is still somehow using an outdated version of Azure despite the fact that I have explicitly been asking Azure to get Pandas 1.4.4, or if the error is coming from somewhere else within my code.

### Edit

I am using the ML Studio in Microsoft Azure to create a machine learning pipeline.

An example of my code (I changed the variable names but the idea is the same) is `new_df = new_df.explode(column = ['name', 'id'], ignore_index = True)`. In my code, `new_df` is a pandas DataFrame which contains two columns called `name` and `id` which contain lists, alongside 15 or so other columns which contain single values (I got the data using a web scraper). The `name` column contains a list of names, and the `id` column contains a list of corresponding IDs. I know for a fact that these lists have the same lengths as this code is able to run without errors locally, and it works as desired.

### Edit

Apparently, Microsoft Azure requires you to use Pandas version 1.0.4 in order to utilize the ML Studio in Azure, so the code which I was attempting to use to install a newer version of pandas was actually not doing anything, as Azure automatically forces you to use 1.0.4 instead of the version which you want.

Comment: Can you tell me which Azure service are you using to run your pandas code? Also, Can you update your code in your question so I can try it in my environment?

Comment: Thank you for asking. I have just updated my post with more context. Please let me know if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried the below code in my Azure ML studio to use Explode function and call lamda function:-***

**Code:-**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

# Create a sample dataframe with a column of lists
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': [['Alice', 'Bob'], ['Charlie', 'David', 'Eve']], 
                   'id': [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], 
                   'value': [10, 20]})

# Print the dataframe
print(df)

# Try to use the explode function with pandas version 1.3.0 or later
try:
    df_exploded = df.explode(column=['name', 'id'], ignore_index=True)
    print(df_exploded)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error using explode:", e)

# Try to use a custom lambda function with pandas apply
try:
    agg_func = pd.api.types.AggFuncType
    df_exploded = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(zip(*x['name'], x['id']))), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame().rename(columns={0: 'name', 1: 'id'}).join(df.drop(['name', 'id'], 1), how='left')
    print(df_exploded)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error using apply:", e)

# Install pandas 1.4.4 using pip
os.system("pip install pandas==1.4.4")

# Check the version of pandas being used
print(pd.__version__)

# Try to use the explode function with pandas version 1.4.4
try:
    df_exploded = df.explode(column=['name', 'id'], ignore_index=True)
    print(df_exploded)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error using explode:", e)
```

**Output ML :-**

****I received the ouput but it threw an exception like below:-****

[image]

I tried changing the pandas version to 1.2.5 , 1.1.5 and 1.4.4 but still received the same error as above.

**Method 1:-**

***As an alternative you can use, the below code for the lamda function and to avoid the above exception:-***

**Code:-**

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

# Create a sample dataframe with a column of lists
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': [['Alice', 'Bob'], ['Charlie', 'David', 'Eve']], 
                   'id': [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]], 
                   'value': [10, 20]})

# Print the dataframe
print(df)

# Try to use the explode function with pandas version 1.3.0 or later
try:
    df_exploded = df.explode('name').explode('id').reset_index(drop=True)
    print(df_exploded)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error using explode:", e)

# Try to use a custom lambda function with pandas apply
try:
    df_exploded = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(zip(*x['name'], x['id']))), axis=1).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_frame().rename(columns={0: 'name', 1: 'id'}).join(df.drop(labels=['name', 'id'], axis=1), how='left')

    print(df_exploded)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error using apply:", e)

# Install pandas 1.4.4 using pip
os.system("pip install pandas==1.4.4")

# Check the version of pandas being used
print(pd.__version__)

# Try to use the explode function with pandas version 1.4.4
try:
    df_exploded = df.explode('name').explode('id').reset_index(drop=True)
    print(df_exploded)
except Exception as e:
    print("Error using explode:", e)
```

**Output ML :-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Output of same code with my local machine:-**

[image]

[image]

**Method 2:-**

***You can also apply the lamda function to the DataFrame element-by-element using the applymap method, as an option.***

**Code:-**

```py
import  pandas  as  pd
# Create a sample dataframe with a column of lists
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': [['Alice', 'Bob'], ['Charlie', 'David', 'Eve']],

'id': [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]],

'value': [10, 20]})

# Print the dataframe
print(df)

# Define a function to apply to each row of the dataframe
def  explode_row(x):
names = x['name']
ids = x['id']

return  pd.DataFrame({'name': names, 'id': ids, 'value': x['value']})

# Apply the explode_row function to each row of the dataframe
df_exploded = df.apply(explode_row, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
# Print the exploded dataframe
print(df_exploded)
```

**Output ML:-**

[image]

**Clear output:-**

```py
import  pandas  as  pd

# Create a sample dataframe with a column of lists

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': [['Alice', 'Bob'], ['Charlie', 'David', 'Eve']],

'id': [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]],

'value': [10, 20]})

# Print the dataframe

print(df)

# Define a function to apply to each row of the dataframe

def  explode_row(x):

names = x['name']

ids = x['id']

return  pd.DataFrame({'name': names, 'id': ids, 'value': x['value']})
 

# Apply the explode_row function to each row of the dataframe

df_exploded = df.explode(column=['name', 'id'], ignore_index=True).reset_index(drop=True)

# Print the exploded dataframe

print(df_exploded)
```

**Output ML:-**

[image]