# Splitting multiple String columns into rows with NaN in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a sample DataFrame as follows:

| **track_id** | **track_date** | **status** | **status_info** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| track_1 | 2021-01-01 | approved | None |
| track_2 | 2021-01-02 | None | accredited |
| track_3 | 2021-01-03 | approved | accredited |
| track_4 | 2021-01-04 | approved | approved |
| track_5 | 2021-01-05 | approved|approved | accredited|cancelled |
| track_6 | 2021-01-06 | None | accredited|cancelled |

And I need to split both `status` and `status_info` into rows, so it gives me an output similar to the one below:

| **track_id** | **track_date** | **status** | **status_info** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| track_1 | 2021-01-01 | approved | None |
| track_2 | 2021-01-02 | None | accredited |
| track_3 | 2021-01-03 | approved | accredited |
| track_4 | 2021-01-04 | approved | approved |
| track_5 | 2021-01-05 | approved | accredited |
| track_5 | 2021-01-05 | approved | cancelled |
| track_6 | 2021-01-06 | None | accredited |
| track_6 | 2021-01-06 | None | cancelled |

I have already tried the code below, using [this answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38651057/7742589) as reference:

```
# splitting string values into lists
new_status = df['status'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
new_status_info = df['status_info'].str.split('|', expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

# generating a temporary DataFrame to join later (error here)
df_split = pd.concat([new_status, new_status_info], axis=1, keys=['status', 'status_info'])

# then, we join both DataFrames
df.drop(columns=['status','status_info'], axis=1).join(df_split).reset_index(drop=True)
```

But it gives me a ValueError:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

When I modify `.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)` to `.reset_index(drop=True)` on the split step, the join operation only brings me one of the values, and not the expected two:

| **track_id** | **track_date** | **status** | **status_info** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| track_1 | 2021-01-01 | approved | None |
| track_2 | 2021-01-02 | None | accredited |
| track_3 | 2021-01-03 | approved | accredited |
| track_4 | 2021-01-04 | approved | approved |
| track_5 | 2021-01-05 | approved | cancelled |
| track_6 | 2021-01-06 | None | accredited |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
cols = ['track_id', 'track_date']

(df.melt(cols, ignore_index=False).reset_index()
   .assign(value=lambda d: d['value'].str.split('|'))
   .explode('value')
   .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
   .pivot(index=cols+['index', 'n'], columns='variable', values='value')
   .reset_index(cols).droplevel('n')
   .groupby(level=0).ffill()
   .rename_axis(index=df.index.name, columns=df.columns.name)
)
```

Output:

```
  track_id  track_date    status status_info
0  track_1  2021-01-01  approved        None
1  track_2  2021-01-02      None  accredited
2  track_3  2021-01-03  approved  accredited
3  track_4  2021-01-04  approved    approved
4  track_5  2021-01-05  approved  accredited
4  track_5  2021-01-05  approved   cancelled
5  track_6  2021-01-06      None  accredited
5  track_6  2021-01-06      None   cancelled
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

df['status'] = df['status'].str.split('|')
df['status_info'] = df['status_info'].str.split('|')

# make `status`, `status_info` columns the same length
df[['status', 'status_info']] = df[['status', 'status_info']].apply(lambda x: [*zip(*zip_longest(x['status'], x['status_info']))], axis=1, result_type='expand')
print(df.explode(['status', 'status_info']))
```

Prints:

```
  track_id  track_date    status status_info
0  track_1  2021-01-01  approved        None
1  track_2  2021-01-02      None  accredited
2  track_3  2021-01-03  approved  accredited
3  track_4  2021-01-04  approved    approved
4  track_5  2021-01-05  approved  accredited
4  track_5  2021-01-05  approved   cancelled
5  track_6  2021-01-06      None  accredited
5  track_6  2021-01-06      None   cancelled
```