# Converting list Dict's to DataFrame: Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I'm doing some web-scraping and I'm storing the variables of interest in form of:

```
a = {'b':[100, 200],'c':[300, 400]}
```

This is for one page, where there were two `b`'s and two `c`'s. The next page could have three of each, where I'd store them as:

```
b = {'b':[300, 400, 500],'c':[500, 600, 700]}
```

When I go to create a `DataFrame` from the list of `dict`'s, I get:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([a, b])

df
                 b                c
0       [100, 200]       [300, 400]
1  [300, 400, 500]  [500, 600, 700]
```

What I'm expecting is:

```
df
     b    c
0  100  300
1  200  400
2  300  500
3  400  600
4  500  700
```

I could create a `DataFrame` each time I store a page and `concat` the list of `DataFrame`'s at the end. However, based on experience, this is very expensive because the construction of thousands of `DataFrame`'s is much more expensive than creating one `DataFrame` from a lower-level constructor (i.e., list of `dict`'s).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38577737/6525140)? Not exactly, but at least both questions are strongly related to each other.

Comment: Iterating over keys, and merging lists seems like the solution you'd like.

Comment: Do you need the `a` and `b` dicts for anything else? If not, you could just keep appending data to dict `a` as you receive it from all pages, then do `df = pd.DataFrame(a)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comprehensions FTW (maybe not the fastest, but can you get any more pythonic?):

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_dicts = [{'b': [100, 200], 'c': [300, 400]},
                 {'b': [300, 400, 500], 'c': [500, 600, 700]}]

def extract(key):
    return [item for x in list_of_dicts for item in x[key]]

df = pd.DataFrame({k: extract(k) for k in ['b', 'c']})
```

EDIT:

I stand corrected. It is just as fast as some of the other approaches.

```
import pandas as pd
import toolz

list_of_dicts = [{'b': [100, 200], 'c': [300, 400]},
                 {'b': [300, 400, 500], 'c': [500, 600, 700]}]

def extract(key):
    return [item for x in list_of_dicts for item in x[key]]

def merge_dicts(trg, src):
    for k, v in src.items():
        trg[k].extend(v)

def approach_AlbertoGarciaRaboso():
    df = pd.DataFrame({k: extract(k) for k in ['b', 'c']})

def approach_root():
    df = pd.DataFrame(toolz.merge_with(lambda x: list(toolz.concat(x)), list_of_dicts))

def approach_Merlin():
    dd = {}
    for x in list_of_dicts:
        for k in list_of_dicts[0].keys():
            try:    dd[k] = dd[k] + x[k]
            except: dd[k] = x[k]
    df = pd.DataFrame(dd)

def approach_MichaelHoff():
    merge_dicts(list_of_dicts[0], list_of_dicts[1])
    df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts[0])


%timeit approach_AlbertoGarciaRaboso()  # 1000 loops, best of 3: 501 µs per loop
%timeit approach_root()                 # 1000 loops, best of 3: 503 µs per loop
%timeit approach_Merlin()               # 1000 loops, best of 3: 516 µs per loop
%timeit approach_MichaelHoff()          # 100 loops, best of 3: 2.62 ms per loop
```

Comment: You can not time my approach like this. My function modifies the given dictionary, thus you are creating very long lists using timeit... Another thing is the performance for integer-lists (and dicts) significantly longer than 2-3 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this change the keys for clarity:

```
a = {'e':[100, 200],'f':[300, 400]}
b = {'e':[300, 400, 500],'f':[500, 600, 700]}
c = {'e':[300, 400, 500],'f':[500, 600, 700]}

listDicts = [a,b,c]
dd= {}

for x in listDicts:
    for k in listDicts[0].keys():
        try:    dd[k] = dd[k] + x[k]
        except: dd[k] = x[k]

df = pd.DataFrame(dd)

     e    f
0  100  300
1  200  400
2  300  500
3  400  600
4  500  700
5  100  300
6  200  400
7  300  500
8  400  600
9  500  700
```

Answer (score 0):

What about simply merging the dictionaries in each step?

```
import pandas as pd

def merge_dicts(trg, src):
    for k, v in src.items():
        trg[k].extend(v)

a = {'b':[100, 200],'c':[300, 400]}
b = {'b':[300, 400, 500],'c':[500, 600, 700]}

merge_dicts(a, b)

print(a)

# {'c': [300, 400, 500, 600, 700], 'b': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]}

print(pd.DataFrame(a))

#     b    c
# 0  100  300
# 1  200  400
# 2  300  500
# 3  400  600
# 4  500  700
```