# Resampling dataframe in pandas as a checking operation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
                            A        B    value
2014-11-14 12:00:00      30.5    356.3      344
2014-11-15 00:00:00      30.5    356.3      347
2014-11-15 12:00:00      30.5    356.3      356
2014-11-16 00:00:00      30.5    356.3      349
...
2017-01-06 00:00:00      30.5    356.3      347
```

I want to check if the index is running every 12 hours, perhaps there is some data missing, so there can be a jump of 24 or more hours. In that case I want to introduce `nan` in the `value` column and copy the values from columns `A` and `B`.

I thought of using `resample`:

```
df = df.resample('12H')
```

but I don't know how to handles the different columns or if this is the right approach.

**EDIT:** If there is a value missing, for instance in `2015-12-12 12:00:00` I would like to add a row like this:

```
...
2015-12-12 00:00:00     30.5    356.3    323
2015-12-12 12:00:00     30.5    356.3    NaN  *<- add this*
2015-12-13 00:00:00     30.5    356.3    347
...
```

Comment: Sorry are you after `df = df.resample('12H').ffill()`? can you show what the desired result should look like

Comment: Ok, I edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `asfreq` method to produce evenly spaced indexes every 12 hours which will automatically put `np.nan` values for every jump. Then you can just forward fill columns A and B.

```
df1= df.asfreq('12H')
df1[['A','B']] = df1[['A','B']].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: With `asfreq` it works, as you said, but with `df1 = df.resample('12H')` is not working, and I think it should be the same. Am I missing something? (I get the `ValueError: cannot set items on DatetimeIndexResampler`.

Comment: `resample` only creates a resample object. It's very analogous to what `groupby` does. You must act on that object to produce a dataframe. Like `df.resample('12H').sum()' or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for simply sorting your dataframe on the index and create a new column that takes the value from the next row (for the time). The current time would be called "from" and the time from the next time would be called "to".

Next step would be to use the two columns ("from" and "to") to create a column containing a list of values between this row and next row for every 12 hours (a range basically).

Final step would be to "explode" every line for each value in the range. Look at [How to explode a list inside a Dataframe cell into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468402/how-to-explode-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-separate-rows)

Hope this helps :)