# Different behaviour with resample and asfreq in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have a dataframe like this:

```
                            A        B    value
2014-11-14 12:00:00      30.5    356.3      344
2014-11-15 00:00:00      30.5    356.3      347
2014-11-15 12:00:00      30.5    356.3      356
2014-11-16 00:00:00      30.5    356.3      349
...
2017-01-06 00:00:00      30.5    356.3      347
```

and I want to be sure that from the beginning until the end there're no missing times (i.e., the index goes from 12 to 12 hours with no bigger jumps). If there is a missing date, for instance, if there is a value missing, for instance in 2015-12-12 12:00:00 I would like to add a row like this:

```
...
2015-12-12 00:00:00     30.5    356.3    323
2015-12-12 12:00:00     30.5    356.3    NaN  *<- add this*
2015-12-13 00:00:00     30.5    356.3    347
```

The question of how to do it was solved here [Resampling dataframe in pandas as a checking operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594155/resampling-dataframe-in-pandas-as-a-checking-operation/41594450#41594450) by @ted-petrou. The solution was doing:

```
df1= df.asfreq('12H')
df1[['A','B']] = df1[['A','B']].fillna(method='ffill')
```

**My question:** Can I do it with `resample` instead of `asfreq`? Doing

```
df1= df.resample('12H')
df1[['A','B']] = df1[['A','B']].fillna(method='ffill')
```

I get `ValueError: cannot set items on DatetimeIndexResampler`. I don't understand why. Are not the same operations `resample` and `asfreq` for this particular case? What am I missing? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that `DF.resample()` is a time-based groupby which must be followed by a reduction method on each of its groups.

So simply using this would only initialize the `Resampler` just like it happens when you call `DF.rolling()` method. Both behave similarly here:

```
df[['A', 'B']].resample('12H')
DatetimeIndexResampler [freq=<12 * Hours>, axis=0, closed=left, label=left, convention=start, base=0]
```

You need to specify an *aggregation function* along with it for it to have a metric for the computation of groups.

Inorder to do this for your case:

1) Use `.resample().ffill()` on the two columns and then join these with the third one. Naturally, since the 3rd wasn't resampled, they would be filled by `NaNs`.

```
df[['A', 'B']].resample('12H').ffill().join(df['value'])
```

2) Use `.resample()` and `.asfreq()` as its `aggfunc` similar to what you have done:

```
df1 = df.resample('12H').asfreq()
df1[['A','B']] = df1[['A','B']].fillna(method='ffill')
```

***Note:***  Employing `.asfreq()` maybe more suitable for frequency conversions than a `.resample` here, if the end goal isn't about aggregating groups.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that I had to add `asfreq()` after the resample. I thought that resampling was enough, like here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html?highlight=resample#pandas.DataFrame.resample This have changed in recent versions. I have Wes McKinney's book and he does it in the old way (I think there is a new version of the book coming soon).

Comment: Yeah, Earlier (perhaps < `v0.18`) `.resample` had a `how` arg which defaulted to taking the mean across groups. But now you need to specify this independently as a following chained syntax.