# explode a csv in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with 200 rows, 2 of which have comma separated values in them. If I output them to tab-separated, it would look like this:

```
col1  col2
a     b,c
d     e,f,g
```

I need to explode to get a dataframe like this, exploding 200 rows into ~4,000:

```
col1  col2
a     b
a     c
d     e
d     f
d     g
```

I don't see any explode functionality in pandas and haven't been able to figure out how to do this having the columns of comma-separated values uneven in length - not sure how split would work here.

Help me stack-overflow, you're my only hope. Thanks!

Comment: I found this, but I do not have my data is a list format - not sure if that's a helpful thread for anyone https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468402/how-to-explode-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-separate-rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `pd.DataFrame`, `.str.split`, `stack`:

```
df_out = (pd.DataFrame(df.col2.str.split(',').tolist(), index=df.col1)
      .stack()
      .reset_index()
      .drop('level_1',axis=1)
      .rename(columns={0:'col2'}))
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2
0    a    b
1    a    c
2    d    e
3    d    f
4    d    g
```

Comment: incredible. mind blown. Thank you! I have 2 csv columns - how would I add a second split column to get all combinations of col1 , col2 (csv), col3(csv)?

Comment: sure, no problem. I'll comment a link here once it's posted.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44361394/exploding-multiple-csv-fields-in-python