# Pandas: per individual, find number of records that are near the current observation. Apply vs transform

Tags: python, pandas, apply, pandas-groupby

Suppose I have several records for each person, each with a certain date. I want to construct a column that indicates, ***per person***, the number of other records that are less than 2 months old. That is, I focus just on the records of, say, individual 'A', and I loop over his/her records to see whether there are other records of individual 'A' that are less than two months old (compared to the current row/record).

Let's see some test data to make it clearer

```
import pandas as pd

testdf = pd.DataFrame({
     'id_indiv': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
     'id_record': [12, 13, 14, 19, 20, 23],
     'date': ['2017-04-28', '2017-04-05', '2017-08-05',
             '2016-02-01', '2016-02-05', '2017-10-05'] })

testdf.date = pd.to_datetime(testdf.date)
```

I'll add the expected column of counts

```
testdf['expected_counts'] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

#Gives:
          date   id_indiv id_record     expected
0       2017-04-28  1       12          1
1       2017-04-05  1       13          0
2       2017-08-05  1       14          0
3       2016-02-01  2       19          0
4       2016-02-05  2       20          1
5       2017-10-05  2       23          0
```

My first thought was to group by `id_indiv` then use `apply` or `transform` with custom function. To make things easier, I'll first add a variable that substracts two months from the record date and then I'll write the `count_months` custom function for the `apply` or `transform`

```
testdf['2M_before'] = testdf['date'] - pd.Timedelta('{0}D'.format(30*2))

def count_months(chunk, month_var='2M_before'):
    counts = np.empty(len(chunk))
    for i, (ind, row) in enumerate(chunk.iterrows()):
        #Count records earlier than two months old
        #but not newer than the current one
        counts[i] = ((chunk.date > row[month_var])
                     & (chunk.date < row.date)).sum()
    return counts
```

I tried first with `transform`:

```
testdf.groupby('id_indiv').transform(count_months)
```

but it gives an `AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'", 'occurred at index date')` which I guess means that `transform` passes a `Series` object to the custom function, but I don't know how to fix that.

Then I tried with `apply`

```
testdf.groupby('id_indiv').apply(count_months)
#Gives

id_indiv
1    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
2    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
dtype: object
```

This almost works, but it gives the result as a list. To "unstack" that list, I followed an answer [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468402/how-to-explode-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-separate-rows):

```
#First sort, just in case the order gets messed up when pasting back:
testdf = testdf.sort_values(['id_indiv', 'id_record'])

counts = (testdf.groupby('id_indiv').apply(count_months)
         .apply(pd.Series).stack()
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))

#Now create the new column
testdf.set_index('id_indiv', inplace=True)
testdf['mycount'] = counts.astype('int')

assert (testdf.expected == testdf.mycount).all()

#df looks now likes this

         date   id_record   expected 2M_before  mycount
id_indiv                    
1       2017-04-28      12      1   2017-02-27  1
1       2017-04-05      13      0   2017-02-04  0
1       2017-08-05      14      0   2017-06-06  0
2       2016-02-01      19      0   2015-12-03  0
2       2016-02-05      20      1   2015-12-07  1
2       2017-10-05      23      0   2017-08-06  0
```

This seems to work, but it seems like there should be a much easier way (maybe using `transform`?). Besides, pasting back the column like that doesn't seem very robust.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

#### Edited to count recent records *per person*

Here's one way to count all records strictly newer than 2 months ***for each person*** using a lookback window of exactly two calendar months minus 1 day (as opposed to an approximate 2-month window of 60 days or something).

```
# imports and setup
import pandas as pd
testdf = pd.DataFrame({
     'id_indiv': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2],
     'id_record': [12, 13, 14, 19, 20, 23],
     'date': ['2017-04-28', '2017-04-05', '2017-08-05',
             '2016-02-01', '2016-02-05', '2017-10-05'] })

# more setup
testdf['date'] = pd.to_datetime(testdf['date'])
testdf.set_index('date', inplace=True)
testdf.sort_index(inplace=True)  # required for the index-slicing below

# solution
count_recent_records = lambda x: [x.loc[d - pd.DateOffset(months=2, days=-1):d].count() - 1 for d in x.index]
testdf['mycount'] = testdf.groupby('id_indiv').transform(count_recent_records)

# output
testdf
            id_indiv  id_record  mycount
date
2016-02-01         2         19        0
2016-02-05         2         20        1
2017-04-05         1         13        0
2017-04-28         1         12        1
2017-08-05         1         14        0
2017-10-05         2         23        0
```

Comment: Thanks and many apologies: I meant that the count should be done per person (I've updated my question to make that clear). I think your code calculates the number of records in a certain window, regardless whether that record belongs to a different person, right?

Comment: Whoops, yeah, this ignores `id_indiv`! I'll edit my answer to address this. Not sure if my solution is better or faster than yours, but at least it'll be an alternative approach.

Comment: @cd98, I've finally edited my answer as promised. I haven't extensively tested the solution, but I hope it's more helpful than my first try.

Answer (score 0):

```
testdf = testdf.sort_values('date')
out_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in testdf.id_indiv.unique():
    for d in testdf.date:
        date_diff = (d - testdf.loc[testdf.id_indiv == i,'date']).dt.days
        out_dict = {'person' : i,
                    'entry_date' : d,
                    'count' : sum((date_diff > 0) & (date_diff <= 60))}
        out_df = out_df.append(out_dict, ignore_index = True)


out_df

    count entry_date  person
0     0.0 2016-02-01     2.0
1     1.0 2016-02-05     2.0
2     0.0 2017-04-05     2.0
3     0.0 2017-04-28     2.0
4     0.0 2017-08-05     2.0
5     0.0 2017-10-05     2.0
6     0.0 2016-02-01     1.0
7     0.0 2016-02-05     1.0
8     0.0 2017-04-05     1.0
9     1.0 2017-04-28     1.0
10    0.0 2017-08-05     1.0
11    0.0 2017-10-05     1.0
```