# Code for exploding a list inside a dataframe cell into rows fails when pandas dataframe is loaded from csv.

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have been trying to explode a list inside a dataframe into expanded/exploded columns like explained on stack overflow [How to explode a list inside a Dataframe cell into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468402/how-to-explode-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-separate-rows?answertab=active#tab-top)

I have been having trouble.

I got the stackoverflow code to work from the example. But I couldn't get it to work for my personal data file (which is on a csv file I used ` pd.read_csv.

I then simplified the code to get rid of one unnecessary column. I got the simplified example code working. Then I tried loading my .csv again. Again, it failed.

So, I took my file out of the equation by writing the data frame from the simplified example to a new csv file, loaded that file using the  pd.read_csv` , and re-ran the simplified "explode" code. I got the same error. Code and error output is below.

```
import pandas as pd

#Create The DataFrame 

df = (pd.DataFrame({ 
                'opponent': ['76ers', 'blazers', 'bobcats'], 
                'nearest_neighbors': [['Zach LaVine', 'Jeremy Lin',       'Nate Robinson', 'Isaia']] * 3})
  .set_index([ 'opponent']))

#Explode The Data Frame

(pd.melt(df.nearest_neighbors.apply(pd.Series).reset_index(), 
     id_vars=[ 'opponent'],
     value_name='nearest_neighbors')
 .set_index([ 'opponent'])
 .drop('variable', axis=1)
 .dropna()
 .sort_index()
)

#Save DF to CSV

df.to_csv("Baskets.CSV")
#Load DF to CSV
df = pd.read_csv("Baskets.csv")

# Re Run Explode Code on csv 

(pd.melt(df.nearest_neighbors.apply(pd.Series).reset_index(), 
         id_vars=[ 'opponent'],
         value_name='nearest_neighbors')
 .set_index([ 'opponent'])
 .drop('variable', axis=1)
 .dropna()
 .sort_index()
 )






KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2441             try:
-> 2442                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2443             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'opponent'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-6ffdc50e8f2c> in <module>()
      1 (pd.melt(df.nearest_neighbors.apply(pd.Series).reset_index(), 
      2              id_vars=[ 'opponent'],
----> 3              value_name='nearest_neighbors')
      4      .set_index([ 'opponent'])
      5      .drop('variable', axis=1)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py in melt(frame, id_vars, value_vars, var_name, value_name, col_level)
    761     mdata = {}
    762     for col in id_vars:
--> 763         mdata[col] = np.tile(frame.pop(col).values, K)
    764 
    765     mcolumns = id_vars + var_name + [value_name]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in pop(self, item)
    548         Return item and drop from frame. Raise KeyError if not found.
    549         """
--> 550         result = self[item]
    551         del self[item]
    552         try:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1962             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   1963         else:
-> 1964             return self._getitem_column(key)
   1965 
   1966     def _getitem_column(self, key):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   1969         # get column
   1970         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 1971             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   1972 
   1973         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1643         res = cache.get(item)
   1644         if res is None:
-> 1645             values = self._data.get(item)
   1646             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1647             cache[item] = res

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3588 
   3589             if not isnull(item):
-> 3590                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3591             else:
   3592                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isnull(self.items)]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2442                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2443             except KeyError:
-> 2444                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2445 
   2446         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'opponent'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial index is being reset to the default index when you save to and then read from the csv file. To fix it, you'll need to read the csv with `index_col` set to `opponent`.

Instead of:

```
#Load DF to CSV
df = pd.read_csv("Baskets.csv")
```

Try using:

```
#Load DF to CSV
df = pd.read_csv("Baskets.csv", index_col='opponent')
```

In order to convert the `nearest_neighbors` column to a list, you will also need to do this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

df.nearest_neighbors=df.nearest_neighbors.apply(literal_eval)
```

After that, I was able to get the melting to work:

```
(pd.melt(df.nearest_neighbors.apply(pd.Series).reset_index(), 
     id_vars=[ 'opponent'],
     value_name='nearest_neighbors')
 .set_index([ 'opponent'])
 .drop('variable', axis=1)
 .dropna()
 .sort_index()
)
```

Output:

```
             nearest_neighbors
opponent                  
76ers          Zach LaVine
76ers           Jeremy Lin
76ers        Nate Robinson
76ers                Isaia
blazers        Zach LaVine
blazers         Jeremy Lin
blazers      Nate Robinson
blazers              Isaia
bobcats        Zach LaVine
bobcats         Jeremy Lin
bobcats      Nate Robinson
bobcats              Isaia
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to use df = pd.read_csv("Baskets.csv", index_col='opponent')  to get it to work.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks!