# Reshaping strings-as-lists into rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({
        'Grouping': ["A", "B", "C"], 
        'Elements': ['[\"A1\"]', '[\"B1\", \"B2\", \"B3\"]', '[\"C1\", \"C2\"]']
    }).set_index('Grouping')
```

so

```
            Elements
Grouping
===============================
A           ["A1"]
B           ["B1", "B2", "B3"]
C           ["C1", "C2"]
```

i.e. some lists are encoded as strings-as-lists.  What is a clean way to reshape this into a tidy data set like this:

```
            Elements
Grouping
====================
A           A1
B           B1
B           B2
B           B3
C           C1
C           C2
```

without resorting to a for-loop?  The best I can come up with is:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df_temp = pandas.DataFrame({'Elements': row['Elements'].replace("[\"", "").replace("\"]", "").split('\", \"')})
    df_temp['Grouping'] = index
    df1 = pandas.concat([df1, df_temp])
df1.set_index('Grouping', inplace=True)
```

but that's pretty ugly.

Comment: How does this come to be in the first-place? Anyway, use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468402/how-to-explode-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-separate-rows?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to "explode" the lists into the data-frame. But first, use `import ast` and `df['Elements'] = df.Elements.map(ast.literal_eval)`. Note that this will be slow, and you'll feel it on huge data-frames, but this is unavoidable unless you fix the situation that got you into this in the first place (I suspect this is an X-Y problem to begin with)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.str.extractall()`:

```
df.Elements.str.extractall(r'"(.+?)"').reset_index(level="match", drop=True).rename({0:"Elements"}, axis=1)
```

the result:

```
         Elements
Grouping         
A              A1
B              B1
B              B2
B              B3
C              C1
C              C2
```

Comment: Nice one dude , never thought we can using `extactall` for these type of questions : -)

Answer (score 1):

You can to convert your 'list' to `list` , then we doing `apply` with `pd.Series` and `stack`

```
import ast
df.Elements=df.Elements.apply(ast.literal_eval)
df.Elements.apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(level=1,drop=True).to_frame('Elements')
         Elements
Grouping         
A              A1
B              B1
B              B2
B              B3
C              C1
C              C2
```

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the `ast` library:  thanks for flagging it.

Comment: @lebelinoz yw : -) happy coding