# How to match between columns in a dataframe and keep another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, dataframe

I would like to get the matches from one column with the other columns in a dataframe. Below is an example:

```
  date        tableNameFrom   tableNameJoin   attributeName
1 29-03-2019  film            language        [film.languageId, language.languageID]
2 30-03-2019  inventory       rental          [invetory.inventoryId, rental.filmId]
```

In the example above, I would like to match between tablenameFrom and tablenameJoin with the attributeName. But, I want to keep the **date** column. Here desired output:

```
  date        tableName    attributeName
1 29-03-2019  film         languageId
2 29-03-2019  language     languageID
3 30-03-2019  inventory    inventoryId
4 30-03-2019  rental       filmId
```

Any idea what should I do? Thank you.

Comment: Is `attributeName` in original dataframe a column of `list` or of `str`?

Comment: @QuangHoang it is a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible approach that [avoids using `apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/4057186)

Raw `DataFrame`

```
         date tableNameFrom tableNameJoin                           attributeName
0  29-03-2019          film      language  [film.languageId, language.languageID]
1  30-03-2019     inventory        rental   [invetory.inventoryId, rental.filmId]
```

Step 1 - (1) Split `attributeName` into 2 separate columns using `,` as the separator, (2) remove unwanted square brackets (`[` or `]`), (3) drop unwanted columns

```
# 1
df[['tableName','attributeName2']] = df['attributeName'].str.split(',', expand=True)

# 2
df['tableName'] = df['tableName'].str.strip('[')
df['attributeName2'] = df['attributeName2'].str.strip(']')

# 3
df.drop(['attributeName','tableNameFrom','tableNameJoin'], axis=1, inplace=True)

print(df)
         date             tableName        attributeName2
0  29-03-2019       film.languageId   language.languageID
1  30-03-2019  invetory.inventoryId         rental.filmId
```

Step 2 - Finally, use [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50731254/4057186) to split the rows from the columns `tableName` and `attributeName2` into separate columns

```
df_match = (df.set_index(['date'])
               .stack()
               .str.split('.', expand=True)
               .stack()
               .unstack(-1)
               .reset_index(-1, drop=True)
               .reset_index()
            )
df_match.columns = ['date','tableName','attributeName']

print(df_match)
         date  tableName attributeName
0  29-03-2019       film    languageId
1  29-03-2019   language    languageID
2  30-03-2019   invetory   inventoryId
3  30-03-2019     rental        filmId
```

**Details**

- `.set_index(['date']` - set the columns that are to be kept as the index of the `DataFrame`
- `.stack()` - stack rows
- `.str.split('.', expand=True)` - call str.split on period (`.`) to split those cells into separate columns
- `.stack()` - get rid of `NULL` values, so call `stack` again
- `.unstack(-1)`

  - since we want the last level of the index to become our columns, so unstack using `unstack(-1)` (unstack on the last level)
  - I have shown this in detail below<sup>1</sup>
- `.reset_index(-1, drop=True)` - eliminate superfluous last level using `reset_index(-1)`

---

<sup>1</sup> Here is the output before the `.unstack(-1)` step and an explanation of why we need to use `-1` inside `unstack()`

```
df_intermediate = (df.set_index(['date'])
                       .stack()
                       .str.split('.', expand=True)
                       .stack()
                )

print(df_intermediate)
date                         
29-03-2019  tableName       0           film
                            1     languageId
            attributeName2  0       language
                            1     languageID
30-03-2019  tableName       0       invetory
                            1    inventoryId
            attributeName2  0         rental
                            1         filmId
dtype: object
```

- this shows that we want the last index level (with values 0, 1) to become the columns so we choose `-1` in `.unstack(-1)`

Answer (score 2):

This may not be what you want, but yields the expected output for the given dataframe:

```
(df.set_index('date').attributeName.apply(pd.Series).stack()
 .reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1).set_index('date')[0]
 .str.split('.').apply(pd.Series)
 )
```

It ignores `tableNameFrome` and `tableNameJoin` and assumes that these are given in `attributeName`.

```
+----+------------+----------+-------------+
|    |       date |        0 |           1 |
|----+------------+----------+-------------|
|  0 | 29-03-2019 |     film |  languageId |
|  1 | 29-03-2019 | language |  languageID |
|  2 | 30-03-2019 | invetory | inventoryId |
|  3 | 30-03-2019 |   rental |      filmId |
+----+------------+----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.drop(["tableNameFrom","tableNameJoin"],inplace=True)
df2=pd.DataFrame()
for row in df.itertuples():
    for i in range(2):
        df2=df2.append(pd.Series(
            [row[1],"".join(row[2][i].split('.')[0]),"".join(row[2][i].split('.')[1])]).T,ignore_index=True)
df2.columns=["date","tableName","tableAttribute"]
df2
```

don't see why you need the middle two columns so i dropped them.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) problem but with an intermediate step to clean up your `attributeName` column:

---

```
# Clean up attributeName column by converting it to string and expanding it by splitting
df = pd.concat([df, df.attributeName.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x).split('.')[1]).str.split(expand=True)], axis=1)\
     .drop('attributeName', axis=1)\
     .rename({0:'attribute1', 1:'attribute2'}, axis=1)
```

Which gives us the following dataframe:

```
print(df)
         date tableNameFrom tableNameJoin   attribute1 attribute2
0  29-03-2019          film      language   languageId   language
1  30-03-2019     inventory        rental  inventoryId     rental
```

---

Then we can use `melt` twice to get the desired output:

```
df1 = df.melt(id_vars='date', value_vars=['tableNameFrom', 'tableNameJoin'], value_name='tableName').drop('variable', axis=1)
df2 = df.melt(id_vars='date', value_vars=['attribute1', 'attribute2'], value_name='attributeName').drop(['variable', 'date'], axis=1)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Which gives us the final output:

```
print(df)
        date  tableName attributeName
0  29-03-2019       film    languageId
1  30-03-2019  inventory   inventoryId
2  29-03-2019   language      language
3  30-03-2019     rental        rental
```