# Explode multiple lists of same length in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas DataFrame with several lists in columns that I would like to split. Each list has the same length and they have to be split at the same indices.

What I have now uses a suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50731258/8084623) but I cannot make it work:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain

split_size = 2

def split_list(arr, keep_partial=False):
    arrs = []
    while len(arr) >= split_size:
        sub = arr[:split_size]
        arrs.append(sub)
        arr   = arr[split_size:]
    if keep_partial:
        arrs.append(arr)
    return arrs


df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 't': [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [0,2]], 'v': [[0,-1,1,0], [0,-1,1,0,2,-2], [0,0]]})

def chainer(lst):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(split_list(lst, split_size)))

def chain_col(col):
    return col.apply(lambda x: chainer(x))

lens = df.t.apply(lambda x: len(split_list(x)))

pd.DataFrame({'id': np.repeat(df.id, lens), 't': chain_col(df.t), 'v': chain_col(df.v)})
```

The problem is that it repeats each *full* list rather than splits it across lines. I think the issue is the usage of `chain.from_iterable` but without it I simply get the list of lists (i.e. split lists) repeated rather than each split to its own row in the DataFrame.

My data set is not very large (a few thousand rows), so if there is a better way I'd be happy to learn. I looked at `explode` but that seems to split the data set based on a single column and I want multiple columns to be split in the same way.

My desired output is for `id = 1` is

```
1. a row with t = [1,2] and v = [0,-1]
2. another row with t = [3,4] = [1,0]
```

*Ideally* I'd add a sub-index to each 'id' (e.g. 1 -> 1.1 and 1.2, so I can distinguish them) but that's a cosmetic thing, not my main problem.

Comment: What would your expected output be for `id = 2`? Would that be one row with `t= [1,2,3], v = [0,-1,1]` and another row with `t=[4,5,6], v=[0,2,-2]`?

Comment: No, for id = 2 the expected output is three rows, each with two elements from the list.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here is one way using a funstion which splits lists to n chunks , then [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) to split each cell , followed by [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and `concat`:

```
def split_lists(l, n):
    """splits a list to n chunks"""
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):  
        yield l[i:i + n]
```

---

```
def explode_multiple(x):
    """This will use the prev func, 
       explode each columns and concat them to a dataframe"""
    m=x.applymap(lambda x: [*split_lists(x,2)])
    m=pd.concat([m.explode(i).loc[:,i] for i in m.columns],axis=1).reset_index()
    return m

explode_multiple(df.set_index('id')) #setting id as index since other columns have list
```

---

```
   id       t        v
0   1  [1, 2]  [0, -1]
1   1  [3, 4]   [1, 0]
2   2  [1, 2]  [0, -1]
3   2  [3, 4]   [1, 0]
4   2  [5, 6]  [2, -2]
5   3  [0, 2]   [0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Using [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html), [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`GroupBy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

*note: this answer uses the new `explode` method only available from `pandas>=0.25.0`*

```
d1 = df.explode('t').drop(columns='v')
d2 = df.explode('v').drop(columns=['id', 't'])

df2 = pd.concat([d1,d2], axis=1)
df2

s = df2.groupby('id')['id'].cumcount()//2

final = df2.groupby(['id', s]).agg({'t':list,
                                    'v':list}).reset_index(level=0)

final['id'] = final['id'].astype(str).str.cat('.'+final.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1).astype(str))
```

**Output**

```
    id       t        v
0  1.1  [1, 2]  [0, -1]
1  1.2  [3, 4]   [1, 0]
0  2.1  [1, 2]  [0, -1]
1  2.2  [3, 4]   [1, 0]
2  2.3  [5, 6]  [2, -2]
0  3.1  [0, 2]   [0, 0]
```