# Python Pandas wrap text in cell output it to_html

Tags: python, html, string, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to wrap text at certain point e.g. `|` in a cell and export that to html.

An example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'EmployeeId': ['157', '292', '643', '124', '355'],
                     'City': ['Mumbai|Bangalore', 'Pune|Mumbai|Delhi', 'Mumbai|Bangalore', 'Mumbai|Pune', 'Bangalore']})

print(df)
df.to_html('test1.html')
```

Output:

```
   EmployeeId      City
0  157        Mumbai|Bangalore 
1  292        Pune|Mumbai|Delhi
2  643        Mumbai|Bangalore 
3  124        Mumbai|Pune      
4  355        Bangalore
```

I would have a html file like this (expected):

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXuem.png)

Output:

```
   EmployeeId  City
0  157        Mumbai
              Bangalore 
1  292        Pune
              Mumbai
              Delhi
2  ...         ...
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: check with str.contains

Answer (score 1):

Basically the idea would be to  use `str.split()` followed by `explode()`. Something like the follwoing code should help.

```
(df.set_index(['EmployeeId']).apply(lambda x:x.str.split('|').explode()).reset_index())
```

The output would be like

```
  EmployeeId       City
0        157     Mumbai
1        157  Bangalore
2        292       Pune
3        292     Mumbai
4        292      Delhi
5        643     Mumbai
6        643  Bangalore
7        124     Mumbai
8        124       Pune
9        355  Bangalore
```

Comment: You may refer to the related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731229/splt-cell-into-multiple-rows-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: (df.set_index(['EmployeeId']).apply(lambda x:x.str.split('|').explode()).reset_index()).groupby(['EmployeeId','City']).count().to_html('test1.html')



I think little additional code may help with this example

Answer (score 1):

Let us do

```
yourdf=df.City.str.split('|').explode().to_frame('City').join(df[df.columns.difference(['City'])])
        City EmployeeId
0     Mumbai        157
0  Bangalore        157
1       Pune        292
1     Mumbai        292
1      Delhi        292
2     Mumbai        643
2  Bangalore        643
3     Mumbai        124
3       Pune        124
4  Bangalore        355
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your helps!

I try this way. I am sure there are better codes.

```
import pandas as pd # Import the data
df = pd.DataFrame({'EmployeeId': ['157', '292', '643', '124', '355'],
                   'City': ['Mumbai|Bangalore', 'Pune|Mumbai|Delhi', 'Mumbai|Bangalore', 'Mumbai|Pune', 'Bangalore']})
#print(df)

df1 = df["City"].str.split("|", expand=True).stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
#print(df1)

df2 = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1, sort=False)
#print(df2)

df2 = df2.drop(["City"], axis=1)
#print(df2)

df2.loc[(df2["EmployeeId"].duplicated()  ), ["EmployeeId"]] = ''
df2.columns = ['EmployeeId', 'City New']
print(df2)

df2.to_html('test1.html')
```

Output:

```
  EmployeeId   City New
0        157     Mumbai
0             Bangalore
1        292       Pune
1                Mumbai
1                 Delhi
2        643     Mumbai
2             Bangalore
3        124     Mumbai
3                  Pune
4        355  Bangalore
```

When export it to_html i get this:

[Image 1: With Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JexsG.png)

Is there anyway to export it like this without grid (maybe with styles)?

[Image 2: Without Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxrAc.png)

Comment: It would be ideal if you update the relevant portion in the question itself, rather than adding  it in  the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, in future i will keep in mind