# Split record DataFrame into several records by separator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

I have dataframe. Examples:

```
df1:
Date       Fruit                Color 
2013-11-23 Banana@Orange       Yellow
2013-11-24 Orange              Orange
2013-11-25 Apple@Strawberry     Green
2013-11-24 Celery               Green
```

I want to receive:

```
df1:
Date       Fruit                Color 
2013-11-23 Banana              Yellow
2013-11-23 Orange              Yellow
2013-11-24 Orange              Orange
2013-11-25 Apple                Green
2013-11-25 Strawberry           Green
2013-11-24 Celery               Green
```

My only idea is to go through the loop, find the delimiter and build a new array.
How else can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split cell into multiple rows in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731229/split-cell-into-multiple-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)(`pandas version >= 0.25`):

```
In [1501]: df1.Fruit = df1.Fruit.str.split('@')
In [1503]: df1.explode('Fruit')               
Out[1503]: 
         Date       Fruit   Color
0  2013-11-23      Banana  Yellow
0  2013-11-23      Orange  Yellow
1  2013-11-24      Orange  Orange
2  2013-11-24       Apple   Green
2  2013-11-24  Strawberry   Green
3  2013-11-24      Celery   Green
```