# How to split a specific selected row to multiple rows using Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, extract

I have a sample dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"Key" : ["First Row", "Sample sample first row: a Row to be splitted $ 369", "Sample second row : a Depreciation $ 458", "Last Row"],
        "Value1" : [365, 265.0, np.nan, 256],
        "value2" : [789, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
print(df)

 
                                Key                           Value1      value2
0                            First Row                          365.0      789.0
1   Sample sample first row: a Row to be splitted $ 369         265.0       NaN
2   Sample second row : a Depreciation $ 458                     NaN        NaN
3    Last Row                                                   256.0       NaN
```

I do know splitting any categories to multiple rows using [Split cell into multiple rows in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731229/split-cell-into-multiple-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

I'm unable to find splitting a row of strings at the selected part.

**Desired output**

```
              Key                  Value1   value2
0        First Row                  365.0    789.0
1   Sample sample first row:        265.0     NaN
2   a Row to be splitted $            369     NaN
3   Sample second row :               NaN     NaN
4   Depreciation $                    458     NaN
5    Last Row                       256.0     NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `split`, `explode`, `extract` and `update`

We can `split` the column `Key` on one or more `space` characters which are preceded by the `:`, then `explode` the dataframe on `Key`, next `extract` the numbers from the `Key` column which are preceded by `$` symbol and `update` the corresponding values in `Value1`

```
df1 = df.assign(Key=df['Key'].str.split(r'(?<=:)\s+')).explode('Key')
df1['Value1'].update(df1['Key'].str.extract(r'\$\s*(\d+)', expand=False).astype(float))
```

---

```
>>> df1
                          Key  Value1  value2
0                   First Row   365.0   789.0
1    Sample sample first row:   265.0     NaN
1  a Row to be splitted $ 369   369.0     NaN
2         Sample second row :     NaN     NaN
2        a Depreciation $ 458   458.0     NaN
3                    Last Row   256.0     NaN
```

Comment: nice use of regex there my friend

Answer (score 3):

in 3 steps using `.explode` `.str.extract()` and `str.replace()`

```
df1 = df.assign(Key=df['Key'].str.split(':')).explode('Key')

df1['Value1'] = df1['Value1'].fillna(
                      df1['Key'].str.extract('\$\s(\d+)').astype(float)[0]
                                  )
df1['Key'] = df1['Key'].str.replace('(\$\s)(\d+)',r'\1',regex=True)
```

---

```
                        Key  Value1  value2
0                 First Row   365.0   789.0
1   Sample sample first row   265.0     NaN
1   a Row to be splitted $    265.0     NaN
2        Sample second row      NaN     NaN
2         a Depreciation $    458.0     NaN
3                  Last Row   256.0     NaN
```