# How to split a row with to multiple rows in csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I need an application to work on CSV files where I need to split one single row into multiple rows based on multiple value in any particular column. It would be better if anyone can help me with python code but any other solution is welcomed. Please help me to solve this. Thanks

Here is the input file: `[![enter image description here][1]][1]`[image]`

And I want to transfer this file into like below: `enter code here`

[image]

If I open the csv file in Notepad++, I can see these as below:
`Name,ID   Club,Position,Inactive,Attendance Date

Arnold Simon,xxxxx,Volleyball - Women's,Player,No,"04/07/2021
04/05/2021"

Arnold Simon,xxxxx,Volleyball - Women's,Safety Officer,No,

Mike Anderson,yyyyy,Volleyball - Women's,Player,No,"04/07/2021
04/05/2021"

Thomas Engle,AAAAA,Volleyball - Women's,Player,No,4/5/2021

Chris Haris,BBBBB,Baseball,Player,No,"07/12/2021
07/11/2021
06/29/2021
06/25/2021
06/16/2021"`

Comment: Is the CSV well-formed regarding multiline fields? I.e. is the value wrapped in quotes or some sort of open/close marker?

Comment: Depending on the answer to that question, [csv.reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) takes an optional `newline` parameter that you can use to allow newlines embedded in a record/field.

Comment: Pandas and itertools give an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731229/split-cell-into-multiple-rows-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @mojo if I open the csv file into notepad++ I see the file as below:                                      Name,ID Club,Position,Inactive,Attendance Date
Arnold Simon,xxxxx,Volleyball - Women's,Player,No,"04/07/2021
04/05/2021"
Arnold Simon,xxxxx,Volleyball - Women's,Safety Officer,No,
Mike Anderson,yyyyy,Volleyball - Women's,Player,No,"04/07/2021
04/05/2021"
Thomas Engle,AAAAA,Volleyball - Women's,Player,No,4/5/2021
Chris Haris,BBBBB,Baseball,Player,No,"07/12/2021
07/11/2021
06/29/2021
06/25/2021
06/16/2021"

Comment: @Sajjad, I can't see newlines or anything in the comment, but I could believe that there are newlines in the "Attendance Date" field data you posted. See what happens with csv.reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it done with this below 1 line code!

`import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('testfile.csv')

res = df.set_index(['Name', 'ID', 'Club','Position','Inactive']).apply(lambda x: x.str.split('\n').explode()).reset_index()

res.to_csv('output.csv')`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this short one:

```py
import csv
with open('input_file.csv') as file:
    new = [row[:-1] + [i] for row in csv.reader(file) for i in row[-1].split()]
with open('output_file.csv', 'w') as file:
    csv.writer(file).writerows(new)
```

Or this equivalent longer one:

```py
import csv
with open('input_file.csv') as f_in, open('output_file.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    csv_out = csv.writer(f_out)
    for row in csv.reader(f_in):
        for i in row[-1].split():
            csv_out.writerow(row[:-1] + [i])
```

Comment: just a little correction for the 2nd one:

import csv

with open('testfile.csv','r') as f_in, open('output_file2.csv','w',newline='') as f_out:
    csv_out = csv.writer(f_out)
    for row in csv.reader(f_in):
        for i in row[-1].split():
            csv_out.writerow(row[:-1] + [i])