# Split lists in a dataframe with different length lists in columns and rows

Tags: python, pandas, explode

So my question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731229/split-cell-into-multiple-rows-in-pandas-dataframe). Mine is different because I have different length lists on the same row and columns.

Many of the solutions I have tried produce a very long dataframe with multiple repeats. My requirements are row wise meaning if a row has a list it is split into the required number of rows but it does not lead to multiple repeats. Please see below example.

Input example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'C1': [["A","B"], ["C"], ["D","E"], ["F"]],
 'C2': [[1], [2], [3], [4]],
 'C3': ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4'],
 'C4': [123, 321, [777,111], 145]})

df
```

[image]

Desired output example

[image]

I have been playing around with `explode()`, `reset_index()`, `drop()` and more but have not been able to get anything to give the correct output yet.

One thing I tried was this

```
df = df.explode("C1").reset_index().drop("index",1).explode("C4").reset_index().drop("index",1)
```

But output was wrong

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the exploded columns and the non-exploded columns need to be separated. Since we can't hide them in the index as we normally do (given `C2`) contains lists (which are unhashable) we must separate the DataFrame then rejoin.

```
# Convert to single series to explode
cols = ['C1', 'C4']
new_df = df[cols].stack().explode().to_frame()
# Enumerate groups then unstack
new_df = new_df.set_index(
    new_df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).cumcount(),
    append=True
).unstack(1).groupby(level=0).ffill()

# Join Back Unaffected columns
new_df = new_df.droplevel(0, axis=1).droplevel(1, axis=0).join(
    df[df.columns.symmetric_difference(cols)]
)
# Re order columns and reset index
new_df = new_df.reindex(df.columns, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

`new_df`:

```
  C1   C2  C3   C4
0  A  [1]  s1  123
1  B  [1]  s1  123
2  C  [2]  s2  321
3  D  [3]  s3  777
4  E  [3]  s3  111
5  F  [4]  s4  145
```

---

We [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) to get all values into a single series then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) together and convert back [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html)

```
cols = ['C1', 'C4']
new_df = df[cols].stack().explode().to_frame()
```

`new_df`

```
        0
0 C1    A
  C1    B
  C4  123
1 C1    C
  C4  321
2 C1    D
  C1    E
  C4  777
  C4  111
3 C1    F
  C4  145
```

We can create a new index by enumerating groups with [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`unstacking`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
new_df = new_df.set_index(
    new_df.groupby(level=[0, 1]).cumcount(),
    append=True
).unstack(1)
```

```
     0     
    C1   C4
0 0  A  123
  1  B  NaN
1 0  C  321
2 0  D  777
  1  E  111
3 0  F  145
```

We can then [`groupby ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html) within index groups:

```
new_df = new_df.groupby(level=0).ffill()
```

`new_df`:

```
     0     
    C1   C4
0 0  A  123
  1  B  123
1 0  C  321
2 0  D  777
  1  E  111
3 0  F  145
```

We can then [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back the unaffected columns to the DataFrame and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to reorder them the way the initially appeared also [`droplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html) to remove unneeded index levels, lastly [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
# Join Back Unaffected columns
new_df = new_df.droplevel(0, axis=1).droplevel(1, axis=0).join(
    df[df.columns.symmetric_difference(cols)]
)
# Re order columns and reset index
new_df = new_df.reindex(df.columns, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

`new_df`:

```
  C1   C2  C3   C4
0  A  [1]  s1  123
1  B  [1]  s1  123
2  C  [2]  s2  321
3  D  [3]  s3  777
4  E  [3]  s3  111
5  F  [4]  s4  145
```

Comment: It's a bit cumbersome. But like you mentioned in my 1.3.0 update post, this is not a well supported operation in `pandas`.

Answer (score -1):

```
 df=df.explode('C4').assign(C1=df['C1'].str.join(',').str.split(',')).explode('C1')#Explode to expand dataframe
m=df.duplicated(subset='C1', keep=False)#loc select the duplicated

df.loc[m,'C4']=df.loc[m,'C4'].shift(1)#Introduce Nan

df.dropna().drop_duplicates(subset='C1', keep='last')#clean dataframe
```

Output

```
   C1   C2  C3   C4
0  A  [1]  s1  123
0  B  [1]  s1  123
1  C  [2]  s2  321
2  D  [3]  s3  777
2  E  [3]  s3  111
3  F  [4]  s4  145
```

Comment: OP doesn't want repeated values in column `C1`

Comment: Looks like this one also works. thanks