# Remove complex duplicated list

Tags: python

I have a weird raw data that contains multiple names in different ways and length.  Something like:

```
data = [
'apple',
'apple;apple(big)',
'apple(apple),apple',
'banana(banana)',
'banana',
nan, # yes, there is some nan datas.
'cookie;cookie(cookie)',
'cookie(choco)']
```

The desired output is the **Shortest** valid name, in the demo case, `output = ['apple', 'banana', 'cookie']`

The way I think about is declaring a `output =[]` and iterate through data and compare if element exists in output, if not, append output; if exists, compare if both have similarities and return one with smaller length. But this seems very inefficient, and I don't know how to compare and get the smallest valid value.

I tried regex too but it failed since the valid result is randomly placed too. How do I complete the task ?

Comment: The code you have posted is NOT a valid python code. Post a  **Valid** code and ask your question.

Comment: Explain how you acquire these data. The *nan* element makes no sense. Maybe it's None. We'd also be very interested to see your RE approach

Answer (score 1):

it looks like values between parens are never valid so (and as stated in comments you have to convert nans into none for valid python code)

```
import re
data=set(y for x in data if x for y in re.split('[,;]', x) if '(' not in y)
>>> {'apple', 'cookie', 'banana'}
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you. The nan data appears cause I scrap it from elements of a dataframe.

Comment: @Cookie please add such information to your question. It might irrelevant to you, but could help us to find the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Assumption: data from pandas' DataFrame or Series

Stumbling about `nan` a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69296142/remove-complex-duplicated-list#comment122479317_69296400) revealed your data source as "elements of a dataframe". So I assume you can use **pandas**, too.

#### Steps

1. removing NaN and reindex (for pandas only)
2. clean data: e.g. 'cookie;cookie(cookie)' to 'cookie,cookie'
3. split by comma and explode (add as rows): e.g. 'cookie,cookie' to separate rows ['cookie', 'cookie']

#### Solution integrated to pandas

For simplicity the data was defined as `Series` (1-dimensional list).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  # to inject NaN values

s = pd.Series([
'apple',
'apple;apple(big)',
'apple(apple),apple',
'banana(banana)',
'banana',
np.nan,  # fixed the syntax
'cookie;cookie(cookie)',
'cookie(choco)'
])

unique = (
    s.dropna()  # remove the NaN values
    .reset_index(drop=True)  # adjust the index as if NaN never existed
    .str.replace(r'\(.*[^)]?', '')  # replace parentheses-enclosed (incl. half-open) by empty string"
    .str.replace(r'[;.]', ',')  # replace semicolon or period by comma
    .str.split(',').explode()  # split to rows (add possible duplicate elements)
    .unique()  # reduce to unique
)

print(type(unique))
print(unique)
```

Prints:

> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
> ['apple' 'banana' 'cookie']

See

- pandas User Guide: [Working with text data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern)
- [Split cell into multiple rows in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731229/split-cell-into-multiple-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear solution too! The comment really helps understanding a lot