# Split dataframe column into equal sublengths and return the new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe such as below and I want to split the string column into rows each with an equal string of 4 characters.

```
date, string
2002-06-01, 12345678
2002-06-02, 87654321
```

Expected Output

```
date, string
2002-06-01, 1234
2002-06-01, 5678
2002-06-02, 8765
2002-06-02, 4321
```

I have tried the example given here: [Split cell into multiple rows in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50731229/split-cell-into-multiple-rows-in-pandas-dataframe)

```
from itertools import chain

def chainer(s):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(s.str.split(df['string'], 4)))

lens = df['string'].str.split(df['string'], 4).map(len)
res = pd.DataFrame({'date': np.repeat(df['date'], lens), 'string': chainer(df['string'])})
```

But I get the error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'. How can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Exlplode Chunks

```
df.assign(
    string=[
        [x[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(x), 4)]
         for x in df.string]
).explode('string')

         date string
0  2002-06-01   1234
0  2002-06-01   5678
1  2002-06-02   8765
1  2002-06-02   4321
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
df.assign(string = df['string'].str.findall(r'\d{4}')).explode('string')
```

Output:

```
       date string
0  6/1/2002   1234
0  6/1/2002   5678
1  6/2/2002   8765
1  6/2/2002   4321
```

Comment: How would you use findall() if it was a string of characters and not digits

Comment: You can just use regex. `r'[A-Za-z]{4}'`