# How to repeat rows based on value of a column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following df that comprises of code/product & weeks columns.

```
code.  Product  .   weeks
123 .  product1 .    1;2
123 .  product1 .    3
321 .  product2 .    4;5;6
321 .  product2 .    7
```

For those rows that have more than 1 week (eg 1;2  or 4;5;6), I want to repeat these rows. My Desirsed output is as follows:

```
code.  Product  .   weeks
123 .  product1 .    1
123 .  product1 .    2
123 .  product1 .    3
321 .  product2 .    4
321 .  product2 .    5
321 .  product2 .    6
321 .  product2 .    7
```

What is the best approach to take using pandas or numpy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to explode a list inside a Dataframe cell into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468402/how-to-explode-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-separate-rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = (df.set_index(['code','Product'])['weeks']
       .str.split(';', expand=True)
       .stack()
       .reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
       .reset_index(name='weeks'))
print (df)
   code   Product weeks
0   123  product1     1
1   123  product1     2
2   123  product1     3
3   321  product2     4
4   321  product2     5
5   321  product2     6
6   321  product2     7
```

**Explanation**:

1. First [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by all repeated columns
2. Create `DataFrame` by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)
3. Reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
4. Last data cleaning by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

Another solution:

```
from itertools import chain

weeks = df['weeks'].str.split(';')
lens = weeks.str.len()
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'code' : df['code'].repeat(lens),
    'Product' : df['Product'].repeat(lens),
    'weeks' : list(chain.from_iterable(weeks.values.tolist())), 
})

print (df)
   code   Product weeks
0   123  product1     1
0   123  product1     2
1   123  product1     3
2   321  product2     4
2   321  product2     5
2   321  product2     6
3   321  product2     7
```

**Explanation**:

1. Create lists by [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html)
2. Get lengths of lsits by [`len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.len.html)
3. Last [`repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.repeat.html) columns and flatten `weeks`

Comment: The first solution appears to be working correctly except for the fact that in my df, it excludes rows that don't have (' ; ') in the  ['weeks'] column value.  To relate back to the original df above, data for weeks 3 and week 7 are not appearing. I think it has something to do with the str.split function accidentally excluding the additional data.  Your help in finding the last missing piece of code will be most helpful!

Comment: @jwlon81 - So first solution failed and second working? If data are not confidental, is possible send me csv to my email in my profile for test it?

Comment: Hi Jezrael,  I'm not sure what happened but I ran the code again and I now works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
#assume test.xlsx is your data
test = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')  
test_processed = pd.DataFrame(columns=test.columns)
for index, row in test.iterrows():
   weeks = row['weeks'].split(';')
   for week in weeks:
       test_processed = test_processed.append({'code':row['code'], 'Product':row['Product'],'weeks':week}, ignore_index=True)
```