# How to check if list is present in row of dataframe and return boolean value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this:

```
col1       col2
1          [1,2]
```

How can I check if df has the list present in the frame so I can apply my flattening logic ?

Example code:

```
if list present in df == TRUE:
     flatten code
else:
     do nothing
```

Comment: You might be better served with methods that do everything in one fell swoop like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468402/how-to-explode-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-separate-rows.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the flatten (unnest and explode ) check the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

How to detect them

```
df.applymap(lambda x : type(x)==list).any()
```