# encode list in a cell in a dataframe with sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'A': 1, 'B': 'p'}, {'A': 1, 'B': 'q'},  {'A': 2, 'B': 'o'},  {'A': 3, 'B': 'p'}])
df
   A  B
0  1  p
1  1  q
2  2  o
3  3  p
```

I could encode and decode it correctly with with code.

```
le = LabelEncoder()
df_encoded = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
df_decoded = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)

for col in df.columns:
    df_encoded[col] = le.fit_transform(df[col])

df_encoded
   A  B
0  0  1
1  0  2
2  1  0
3  2  1

for col in df.columns:
    le = le.fit(df[col])
    df_decoded[col] = le.inverse_transform(df_encoded[col])

df_decoded

   A  B
0  1  p
1  1  q
2  2  o
3  3  p
```

Now if I have a data frame like this, how can I encode and decode it?

```
dj = pd.DataFrame([{'A': [1,2], 'B': 'p'}, {'A': 1, 'B': ['p','q']},  {'A': 2, 'B': 'o'},  {'A': 3, 'B': 'p'}])
```

I want to have a code for each cell of ['p','q'] instead of a code for ['p','q'].

Comment: have you checked this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468402/how-to-explode-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-separate-rows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to break down the cells that include lists into separate rows, then apply LabelEncoder, and then combine these rows back into lists:

```
df_encoded = pd.DataFrame()
df_decoded = pd.DataFrame()

def t1(z):
    zz = pd.DataFrame([np.array(x).reshape(-1) for x in z.values.tolist()])
    dt = zz.dtypes[0]
    return (zz
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .to_frame(col)
        .astype(dt))

def t2(z):
    return z.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: np.squeeze(x.values.tolist()))

for col in dj.columns:
    d = t1(dj[col])
    d['x'] = le.fit_transform(d[col])
    df_encoded[col] = t2(d['x'])

print(df_encoded)

for col in dj.columns:
    d = t1(dj[col])
    m = le.fit(d[col])

    d = t1(df_encoded[col])
    d['x'] = m.inverse_transform(d[col])
    df_decoded[col] = t2(d['x'])

print(df_decoded)
```

Output:

```
        A       B
0  [0, 1]       1
1       0  [1, 2]
2       1       0
3       2       1

        A       B
0  [1, 2]       p
1       1  [p, q]
2       2       o
3       3       p
```

Comment: Updated the answer to include both encode and decode