# Transform an Array of Objects into a Dataframe without a loop

Tags: python, pandas

This is my original dataframe. Every row has an email and a list of addresses (There is just street to exemplify).

```
email                      addresses

somename@gmail.com         [{'street': 'a'}, {'street': 'b'}]
anothername@gmail.com      [{'street': 'c'}]
```

And I expect this result:

```
email                         street

somename@gmail.com            'a'
somename@gmail.com            'b'
anothername@gmail.com         'c'
```

Is there a better way in pandas than iterate over the array to create this last dataframe?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468402/how-to-explode-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-separate-rows

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'email':df.email.repeat(df.addresses.str.len()),\
                   'addresses':np.concatenate(df.addresses.values)})
df1['street']=df1.pop('addresses').apply(pd.Series)
print(df1)

                   email street
0     somename@gmail.com      a
0     somename@gmail.com      b
1  anothername@gmail.com      c
```

Comment: This is a really nice elegant solution! `df.addresses.str.len()` grabs the length of the dicts rowwise, didnt know.