# How to optimize code to make a list that's stacked up vertically based on Pandas column values?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a DataFrame (test_df) that looks like,

```
Year    Month   TAGS
2019    5   A, B
2019    5   A, C
2019    5   A
2019    5   
2019    5   B, C, D
2019    5   C, E
```

I would like to get a Tags LIST that looks like this stacked up vertically when I split the tags string by comma.

```
A
B
A
C
A
B
C
D
C
E
```

I utilized 2 For loops in order to get the list of tags

```
check=[]

for j in range(len(test_df)): 

  for i in range(len(test_df['TAGS'][j].split(', '))):

      check.append(test_df['TAGS'][j].split(', ')[i])
```

Is there a better way to get the TAGS list without the use of 2 For loops.

Comment: Are your Tags a single character or really anything separated by a comma?

Comment: Did you try `test_df['TAGS'].tolist()`

Comment: Still iterating, but try `itertools.chain.from_iterable(s.split(', ') for s in df.TAGS if s is not None)`.  Should be faster than your current approach

Comment: Also, can you verify. Do you have a Series of Lists `['A', 'B']` or a Series of strings `'A, B'`? If they're lists it's just `pd.Series(chain.from_iterable(df.Tags))`

Comment: @arajshree, If I do test_df['TAGS'].tolist(), I get as A,B \n A,C \n A \n B,C,D \n C,E but i expect something as A \n B \n A \n C \n A \n B \n C \n D \n C \n E

Comment: @ALollz, It's not a single character but anything separated by comma

Comment: are you looking for `df["TAGS"].str.split(", ").apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(drop=True)`?

Comment: @pault, this is it.. Your suggestion worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can first split the `TAGS` column on `", "`:

```
df["TAGS"].str.split(", ")
#0       [A, B]
#1       [A, C]
#2          [A]
#3         None
#4    [B, C, D]
#5       [C, E]
```

Then adapt the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46161733/5858851) to get your final output:

```
df["TAGS"].str.split(", ").apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
#0    A
#1    B
#2    A
#3    C
#4    A
#5    B
#6    C
#7    D
#8    C
#9    E
```