# Check if item in DataFrame exists from a list of items

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter.optionmenu

I couldn't find this anywhere, so I hope someone can help me.

I have a window written with tkinter, which contains an OptionMenu. The OptionMenu consists of the numbers 1 to 4 and the option 'all':

[image]

Now this OptionMenu is used as a filter for a dataframe and here comes the problem right a away.
Before, I simply used the following code to filter the dataframe:

```
value_term = ['3']
df_filtered= df[(df['Term'].astype(str).isin(value_term))]
```

Which works when there is only one number in each dataframe cell:

[image]

The option 'all' works because I used this code:

```
value_term = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Which enables me to not filter the dataframe. Now the problem is that there is a new situation, which cannot be handled by this:

[image]

As you can see, this cell contains two number separated by a semicolon. I tried using this code:

```
df_filtered= df[(df['Term'].astype(str).str.contains(value_term))]
```

Which works for when the input is one number (as string), but I have no idea how to make sure that the list is not filtered when the user chooses 'all'. The closest option would be: use an if-statement, but the code that I just showed has only one filter while the real code has more:

```
df_filtered= df[(df['Mandatory'].str.contains(value_track))
                          & (df['Term'].astype(str).isin(value_term))
                          & (df['Points'].astype(str).isin(value_ECTS))
                          & (df['Type'].isin(value_type))
                          & (df['TP'].isin(value_tech_ppd))
                          & (df['Theme'].isin(value_theme))]
```

Does someone know how to do this?

Best,
Ganesh

Comment: you may need to convert this cell to a list, and them explode the cell in to new rows, and use your method.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468402/how-to-explode-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-separate-rows

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately.