# how to make long format using one column (has a list of items) in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a data frame that has one column, values, with a list of items within it.

Below is data frame I have:

```
| uniqId   | DeptId  | Date       | values     |
| -------- | ------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 1234     | BKNG    | 2023-09-05 | [VGM, FJK] |
| 2534     | FINA    | 2023-09-04 | [GTD, WEH] |
| 3469     | ASKG    | 2023-09-05 | [MUG, PIS] |
```

And I want to achieve the output as:

```
| values_1 | uniqId   | DeptId  | Date       | values     |
| -------- | -------- | ------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| VGM      | 1234     | BKNG    | 2023-09-05 | [VGM, FJK] |
| FJK      | 1234     | BKNG    | 2023-09-05 | [VGM, FJK] |
| GTD      | 2534     | FINA    | 2023-09-04 | [GTD, WEH] |
| WEH      | 2534     | FINA    | 2023-09-04 | [GTD, WEH] | 
| MUG      | 3469     | ASKG    | 2023-09-05 | [MUG, PIS] |
| PIS      | 3469     | ASKG    | 2023-09-05 | [MUG, PIS] |
```

The original values column stays with the data frame and create new column called `values_1`, with each item from the list in Values listed as its own column with rest of the data columns as is.

Can someone please help me with this?

I know that pandas melt or pandas long function can be utilized but I was not sure how to apply to a column that contains list.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-melt/

Thanks!

Comment: What is `[VGM, FJK]`? Its not a python list, which would display with some sort of literal like `"VGM"` for strings or `123` for integers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to explode a list inside a Dataframe cell into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32468402/how-to-explode-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-separate-rows)

Comment: @Vitalizzare, Thank you for posting the link. This look like would have worked for my use case. Thanks for posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
cp = df["values"]
df = df.explode("values")

df = df.rename(columns={"values": "values_1"}).assign(values=cp)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   uniqId DeptId        Date values_1      values
0    1234   BKNG  2023-09-05      VGM  [VGM, FJK]
0    1234   BKNG  2023-09-05      FJK  [VGM, FJK]
1    2534   FINA  2023-09-04      GTD  [GTD, WEH]
1    2534   FINA  2023-09-04      WEH  [GTD, WEH]
2    3469   ASKG  2023-09-05      MUG  [MUG, PIS]
2    3469   ASKG  2023-09-05      PIS  [MUG, PIS]
```

Comment: thank you for your time and posting the answer on this. Appreciate it. This solution worked for my dataset. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Another possible option :

```
out = df.loc[(ser:=df["values"].explode()).index].assign(values_1=ser)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   uniqId DeptId        Date      values values_1
0    1234   BKNG  2023-09-05  [VGM, FJK]      VGM
0    1234   BKNG  2023-09-05  [VGM, FJK]      FJK
1    2534   FINA  2023-09-04  [GTD, WEH]      GTD
1    2534   FINA  2023-09-04  [GTD, WEH]      WEH
2    3469   ASKG  2023-09-05  [MUG, PIS]      MUG
2    3469   ASKG  2023-09-05  [MUG, PIS]      PIS
```

Comment: Wow!  Looking at the smart way you are using .loc and the index here.  This is really efficient use of the walrus operator here. +1   I like it a lot!

Comment: Thank you @Scott Boston. The funny thing is that I was inspired by you. You’re the first one I saw using walrus in a pandas context ;)

Comment: IMO you're overcomplicating things. The whole answer is _join exploded column_, sort of `df.join(df['values'].explode().rename('something'))`, nothing interesting or complex. Also OP is an obvious duplicate. So I wonder, don't you think it should be closed and why?

Comment: @Vitalizzare Take a look at the timings of using join versus the above method.   "Re-indexing" using loc and index this way and assign that exploded value as a new column is way more computationally efficient that joining these two objects together.

Comment: @ScottBoston Okey, don't you think this info and some comparison should be a part of the answer? All I can see is _"another possible option"_ with no explanation why and when this options is good.

Comment: @ScottBoston, Thank you for your time and posting answer with nice trick in walrus operator. Unfortunately, this is giving me indent syntax error and did not work on my side. However, I am assuming that this is due to "values_1" column not present in the original dataframe perhaps. Thanks.

Comment: @TarakPandya  Walrus is new to Python in 3.8.  But yes, the other answer works well get your answer.  No, it isn't that values_1 doesn't exists, it is because ser doesn't exists without walrus assignment.  pd.DataFrame.assign is creating a new columns 'values_1'.

Comment: @ScottBoston, Appreciate it your explanation. This is handy trick to keep. Again, Thanks!