# how to ungroup a df row when row element is a list

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

i have a pandas dataframe where elements of col2 are lists. i would like to ungroup the rows and get a row for each element in the lists in col2
For example my dataframe looks like

```
col1, col2
0, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1, [0]
1, [1, 2]
```

how to convert the above dataframe to look like this:

```
col1, col2
0, 0
0, 1
0, 2
0, 3
0, 4
1, 0
1, 1
1, 2
```

i have tried using `df.explode('col2')` but it is converting each element of the list into its own list which is not what i need.

```
col1, col2
0, [0]
0, [1]
0, [2]
0, [3]
0, [4]
1, [0]
1, [1]
1, [2]
```

Comment: It's not possible to reproduce your problem with your input data. `explode` should give the expected output. (or maybe you have an old version of Pandas?)

Comment: When a list or dictionary is included in a cell, **provide example of input as code**.

Comment: Please add the output of print(df.to_dict()) so we get a view of your actual input data.

Answer (score 0):

Use double `explode`, because seems there are nested lists:

```
df.explode('col2').explode('col2')
```

Or select first element in list and assign back:

```
df.explode('col2').assign(col2 = lambda x: x.col2.str[0])
```

Comment: What did you mean with nested lists? Has the provided data changed?

Comment: @OCa - Because ouput after `df.explode('col2')` is nested lists. I think like `[0]`

Comment: finally understood 1) the question 2) that again you were right all along ^^ It seems the provided input data is inexact.

Answer (score 0):

Using this constructor:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['col1', 'col2'],
                   data = [[0, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
                           [1, [0]],
                           [1, [1, 2]]])
df1
   col1             col2
0     0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
1     1              [0]
2     1           [1, 2]
```

A simple `explode` suffices: (as stated in the [pands docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/user_guide/reshaping.html#exploding-a-list-like-column) and exemplified here: [How to explode a list inside a Dataframe cell into separate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32468402/12846804))

```
df1.explode(column='col2')

   col1 col2
0     0    0
0     0    1
0     0    2
0     0    3
0     0    4
1     1    0
2     1    1
2     1    2
```

This prompts the question of what your real dataframe is. **Please add the output of `print(df.to_dict())` so we get a clear view of your input data.**

Indeed as @jezrael hinted for, *this* below might be the data you are actually working with:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['col1', 'col2'],
                   data = [[0, [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]],
                           [1, [[0]]],
                           [1, [[1], [2]]]])

df2

   col1                       col2
0     0  [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]
1     1                      [[0]]
2     1                 [[1], [2]]
```

Because *that* yields your undesired output:

```
df2.explode('col2')

   col1 col2
0     0  [0]
0     0  [1]
0     0  [2]
0     0  [3]
0     0  [4]
1     1  [0]
2     1  [1]
2     1  [2]
```